# What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

What's the reason why Java doesn't allow us to do

```
private T[] elements = new T[initialCapacity];
```

I could understand .NET didn't allow us to do that, as in .NET you have value types that at run-time can have different sizes, but in Java all kinds of T will be object references, thus having the same size (correct me if I'm wrong).

What is the reason?

Comment: What are you talking about?  You can absolutely do this in .NET. -- I'm here trying to figure out why I can't do it in Java.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 - please add a link to some code example or tutorial which shows that.

Comment: Also see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577493/why-not-create-an-object-and-cast-to-a-generic-type-whats-the-solution

Comment: @MasterJoe2 the above code in the OP's question is what I'm referring to.  It works fine in C#, but not in Java. -- The question states it works in neither, which is incorrect. -- Not sure there's value in discussing it further.

Comment: [Because it's a bug that hasn't been fixed yet.
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlOJI.jpg)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

It's because Java's arrays (unlike generics) contain, at runtime, information about its component type. So you must know the component type when you create the array. Since you don't know what `T` is at runtime, you can't create the array.

Comment: But what about erasure? Why doesn't that apply?

Comment: How does `ArrayList <SomeType>` do it then?

Comment: @Thumbz: You mean `new ArrayList<SomeType>()`? Generic types do not contain the type parameter at runtime. The type parameter is not used in creation. There is no difference in the code generated by `new ArrayList<SomeType>()` or `new ArrayList<String>()` or `new ArrayList()` at all.

Comment: I was asking more about how `ArrayList<T>` works with its' `private T[] myArray`.  Somewhere in the code, it must have an array of generic type T, so how?

Comment: @Thumbz: It doesn't have an array of runtime type `T[]`. It has an array of runtime type `Object[]`, and either 1) the source code contains a variable of `Object[]` (this is how it is in the latest Oracle Java source); or 2) the source code contains a variable of type `T[]`, which is a lie, but doesn't cause problems due to `T` being erased inside the scope of the class.

Comment: @Thumbz: yes, if you go with route #2

Comment: @newacct How odd.  Aren't references == pointers, which would mean they're all the same size (the size of an address)?  If this is true, then the size should already be known, and if not, it seems you could just say something like `class CustomArray<TYPE extends Object>  {  TYPE [] myArray = new TYPE [42];  }` and it should be able to do exactly the same thing without giving any warnings.

Comment: @Thumbz: You can *access* array elements without any difference. But if you get the type of the array object itself, it will be wrong. For various reasons, Java arrays are reified (they know their component type at runtime), and `String[]` implies the array it points to actually has runtime component type `String` or subtype thereof, not just that it's an array that contains `String`s. It's been that way from the first version of Java, before Generics, and cannot be changed.

Comment: @newacct:  I'm not totally sure I follow, but I still don't see why `<TYPE extends String> []` is a very different concept from `String []`.  If you know at least one class from which TYPE inherits from, it seems that the compiler should be able to read `class la<T extends Object>  {  T [] lala = new T[42];  }` and equivocate that to `{  Object [] lala = new Object[42];  }`

Comment: @Thumbz: In Java, `String[] foo = (String[])new Object[5];` is fine at compile time but causes an exception at runtime. It's just a historical fact of how arrays in Java were made that `String[]` and `Object[]` are two different classes at runtime. `new Object[42]` creates an object of runtime class `Object[]`, and it's not safe to consider that as `T[]` because if you have a method that exposes that to the outside of the class as type `T[]`, like `T[] getArray{ return lala; }`, and someone calls that on a `CustomArray<String>` and assigns the result to a `String[]`, they will get an exception

Comment: If it causes an exception at run time, then how is it done in `ArrayList`? There must be some way of creating a `T[]` that doesn't cause exceptions.

Comment: @Thumbz: What makes you think there needs to be a `T[]`? Like I said, they could 1) have the variable of type `Object[]`, and cast to `T` when they get an element out of it, or 2) have the variable of type `T[]` but it's actually still of runtime class `Object[]`, and be careful not to expose it to the outside of the class. The two approaches are the same after erasure.

Comment: Why do you not know T at runtime?

Comment: @committedandroider: where would you get it from at runtime?

Comment: Say we have the List ADT, When the client initializes ArrayList(and runs the program), he or she does it by List<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ? Basically, you get when it is being used?

Comment: @committedandroider: Nope. That is exactly the same as `List list = new ArrayList();`

Comment: Oh so user doesn't have to specify type parameter when initializing?

Comment: @committedandroider: The user doesn't have to specify a type parameter, and specifying the type parameter doesn't change the compiled byte code. It's only used for compile-time type checking only.

Comment: The answer is not clear. In fact the topic need separate blog post to be explained. See my next comment.

Comment: The problem is deeper than pointed in that answer, so further investigation is needed. As you said type info is erased and in compiled code we have no difference between two generic types - all we have is base type - so why for T[] - compile to Object[]. In this case everything will be fine - array will remember that it was created with object type and will let save all types. However as for me the real problem is that arrays are covariant  meaning that Animal[] can be assigned to Object[]. in other hand generics are not ArrayList<Animal> can not be assigned to ArrayList<Object>

Comment: This is how i understand the topic at the time - that can be wrong. If you think this is wrong - please give me reference to the documentation or other source of truth :)

Comment: why do python do not have such problems ?

Comment: this same thing happens when you try to instantiate a specific template object array, this should not happen, the types are clearly defined and not generic. like MyClass<Long>[] myclasstemplatearray = new MyClass<Long>[5];

Comment: @Goofyseeker311: Array component types can only be reifiable types. The reason is that an array promises to check at runtime that everything put into it is either `null` or an instance of the component type, or it will throw an `ArrayStoreException`. But it's not possible to check at runtime whether something is an instance of a parameterized type. So a `MyClass<Long>[]` cannot fulfill its promise. Now, you could create an array of the raw type, i.e. `MyClass[]`, but it will only check at runtime that things put into it are `MyClass` (which it can fulfill).

Comment: @newacct are generic classes full Object's and therefore Class'es? there is your answer, no matter what terminology you would use. if you can array any object then you can array any template style object also. I hear and see a generic not adhering to the Object contract in here. I Object to the choices the language designers and implementers made in the Object'ion case.

Comment: you could make a linked list that only references the generic type as singular, but acts like an array. whats the difference. none. you could do arrays but Java fathers did not come to the conclusion that you could do it. sad. if you can use a generic typed class in other data structures, but not in arrays, that sounds very fishy. non-sense decision by the designers. end of story.

Comment: could you bypass the array definition by just defining an Object[] array, then assigning the generics to the Object[] array, then just cast them to the generic type...

Comment: yes you can create an Object[] array of the generic objects. just casting them back requires an unchecked cast suppression if you dont want any Object'ion from the compiler. just tried it out also and works fine with Integer generic objects in the Object[] array.

Comment: you just have to trick the compiler this way so it does not Object. therefore only an artificial limitation by designing limitations.

Comment: therefore generic objects are fully legal proper objects also in (Object[]) arrays.

Comment: @Goofyseeker311: Like I said, an array-of-generic-type type cannot fulfill the full contract of arrays. You can still make an array of a raw type, and then do an unchecked conversion to an array of a generic type, but you get an unchecked warning, which gives you notice that something potentially unsafe may happen, potentially at an unexpected place down the line. If you are sure that those things that are unsafe do not affect your use case, then you can continue, but you take responsibility for it.

Comment: I call that nonsense, any created entity needs to be a full object, you take the responsibility of trying to block it, to be done in the fully typed way, you are in the way, not helping, thanks. you make and keep a legal thing illegal. no thanks. so you are acting and trying to be the law. I dont believe in you law. there is nothing unsafe in creating arrays of generic objects. if they are not objects they dont exist. at all. your reasoning is not sound. your reasoning is unsafe. there is nothing unsafe in generic arrays. you block the syntax in vain.

Comment: stop blocking the free usage of generic typed arrays, make it so that the runtime type of the generic array is fully acknowledged, stored and used in the objects, if its not so already. do the forced casting internally and allow the generic typed array new construction by default. period. so you can make generic arrays, hmh. stop pretending you cant do so. YOU dont allow generic arrays. stop arguing back as the law. your blocking of the typed generic array new generation makes all things not type safe. let go of your resistance. confess that you are wrong. your ruling? no.

Comment: casting objects into other types is a fully valid and safe way to deal with objects, it makes generic object arrays fully valid even if it falsely generates a warning by the compiler or programming IDE. YOU try to limit usage of such things. not good. casting fear will not work anymore. believing in you is dangerous. stop blocking people with your limiting laws and rulings. so you claim MyClass<T> is not an object type and a class?

Comment: omg so you claim that the compiler does not know the runtime type of the class, even if it has all the information in the signature of the generic object type. but I can force the type myself when I know what type the Object class type object is, manually. this is nonsense. who are you, you saying something does not mean its like you say it is. stop claiming nonsense reasonings. just use the forced unchecked cast Object[] arrays freely to bypass language syntax barriers!!

Comment: unnecessary limiters of freedom, the law syntax checkers. so throw an exception if the class is not the same runtime type generic object class than what was compiled to be, what's the problem and difficulty in that?

Comment: God said to never to fear/believe in people, do you believe? such are the beasts of this world, the king rulers, of the air. As I said, its dangerous to believe in you and your limitations law rulings.

Comment: whatever authority as a teacher you had until now, you dont have anymore.

Comment: @Goofyseeker311: Like I said, arrays perform a runtime type check on things put into them. e.g. the following compiles perfectly fine but will throw an `ArrayStoreException` at runtime: `Integer[] a = new Integer[5]; Object[] b = a; b[2] = "foo";`. Runtime type checks can only be done with reifiable types. You cannot check whether something is a `MyClass<Integer>` at runtime, because objects do not know their generic type argument at runtime. There is no difference at runtime between something created as a `new ArrayList<Integer>()` vs `new ArrayList<String>()`.

Comment: @Goofyseeker311: So here is the same example as above, but with generic types, and it is unsafe: `ArrayList<Integer>[] a = new ArrayList[5]; Object[] b = a; ArrayList<String>[] c = new ArrayList[7]; b[2] = c;` This compiles and throws no exceptions at runtime. Now `a[2]` will point to `c` (an `ArrayList<String>`), even though `a[2]` has type `ArrayList<Integer>`. That is incorrect. You can then store `Integer` objects in through `a` and try to get them out via `c`, and get a `ClassClastException`, even though there is no cast and no warning at the place where you get the element out.

Comment: lawmakers excuse is always "not safe". same goes for the police who act as the servants of the law, "not safe". so its only about the compiler not pretending to know the runtime type. right. case over. fix the compiler.

Comment: I consider all these considerations to be fake worry excuses not doing things right but purposefully blocking the proper free way with limiting laws lawmakers and police and gov, by general agreements. not agreed.

Comment: so this is why kotlin or other versions of java get made, then the original gets stuck with its head on a bush, in the biblical sense.

Comment: ok last comment: any compiler could just convert any "cant create generic array" to the Object[] creation code segment and it would compile fine. stop complaining and blocking "can" with "cant/dont/should/scary/worry/not-safe". to be "safe" you only need to know that the object class specification as the typed generic object is the one you expect. with the identical access interface definition. nothing else. this fulfills the Object and class specification to the T of the Java specification, disregarding the offending limiting generic object rules and limitations.

Comment: do you want to try to follow a minor rule when discarding a major rule, in the Java specification. yes you chose to implement and enforce a minor rule breaking a major rule. you broke Java with your own non-ordered minor rules application priority. what if your generic template says you are a guru level programmer but I deny you to be generic type of the programming guru?

Answer (score 152):

Quote:

> Arrays of generic types are not
>   allowed because they're not sound. The
>   problem is due to the interaction of
>   Java arrays, which are not statically
>   sound but are dynamically checked,
>   with generics, which are statically
>   sound and not dynamically checked.
>   Here is how you could exploit the
>   loophole:
>
> ```
> class Box<T> {
>     final T x;
>     Box(T x) {
>         this.x = x;
>     }
> }
>
> class Loophole {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         Box<String>[] bsa = new Box<String>[3];
>         Object[] oa = bsa;
>         oa[0] = new Box<Integer>(3); // error not caught by array store check
>         String s = bsa[0].x; // BOOM!
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> We had proposed to resolve this
>   problem using statically safe arrays
>   (aka Variance) bute that was rejected
>   for Tiger.
>
> -- [gafter](http://forums.sun.com/profile.jspa?userID=12373)

(I believe it is [Neal Gafter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241658/neal-gafter), but am not sure)

See it in context here: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=457033&forumID=316

Comment: Note that I made it a CW since the answer is not mine.

Comment: This explains why it might not be typesafe. But type safety issues could be warned by the compiler. The fact is that it is not even possible to do it, for almost the same reason why you cannot do `new T()`. Each array in Java, by design, stores the component type (i.e. `T.class`) inside it; therefore you need the class of T at runtime to create such an array.

Comment: You still can use `new Box<?>[n]`, which might be sometimes sufficient, although it wouldn't help in your example.

Comment: @BartKiers I don't get it... this still does not compile (java-8) : `Box<String>[] bsa = new Box<String>[3];` did anything change in java-8 and up I assume?

Comment: @Eugene, Arrays of specific generic types simply aren't allowed becuase they can lead to a loss of type safety as demonstrated in the sample. It is not allowed in any version of Java. The answer starts as "Arrays of generic types are not allowed because they're not sound. "

Comment: @BartKiers - Can we  do this instead "T[ ] elements = new T[num]" ?

Comment: any generic object is a sound object, try making an Object[] array of them, I think I just bypassed a syntax check limitation of the language. works well in the tests also.

Answer (score 67):

By failing to provide a decent solution, you just end up with something worse IMHO.

The common work around is as follows.

```
T[] ts = new T[n];
```

is replaced with (assuming T extends Object and not another class)

```
T[] ts = (T[]) new Object[n];
```

I prefer the first example, however more academic types seem to prefer the second, or just prefer not to think about it.

Most of the examples of why you can't just use an Object[] equally apply to List or Collection (which are supported), so I see them as very poor arguments.

Note: this is one of the reasons the Collections library itself doesn't compile without  warnings.  If this use-case cannot be supported without warnings, something is fundamentally broken with the generics model IMHO.

Comment: You have to be careful with the second one. If you return the array created in such a way to someone who expects, say, a `String[]` (or if you store it in a field that is publicly accessible of type `T[]`, and someone retrieves it), then they will get a ClassCastException.

Comment: I voted this answer down because your preferred example is not permitted in Java and your second example may throw a ClassCastException

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior It is quite clear the first example needs to be replaced with the second example. It would be more helpful for you to explain why the second example can throw a ClassCastException as it wouldn't be obvious to everyone.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I created a self-answered question showing why `T[] ts = (T[]) new Object[n];` is a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577493/why-not-create-an-object-and-cast-to-a-generic-type-whats-the-solution

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I downvoted him because 1) The OP asked why he can't do that in java and not how he could do, so he didn't answered the question. 2) He said his answer has 2 example because he prefer the first example but has actually only one. 3) He's only example doesn't create a T[] but creates an Object[] that can cause issues. My self-answered question is not related to this question but is related to the question Peter did, he asked me to explain why he's example can throw an exception because it was not clear, so I explained in a different question

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The OP is not asking opinions, he's asking explanation why he can't do `new T[initialCapacity]` when `T` is a generic class, he's asking this because he don't understand why java disallows it. Also, _alternative disign choice which someone would have liked better_ would be a chatty topic and would be against stackoverflow rules [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I should be given a medal for answering all your comments to explain the same thing I've already said, the only thing that changed from my original reason is that I though that he said `T[] ts = new T[n];` was a valid example. I'll keep the vote because he's answer can cause issues and confusions to other devs and is also off-topic. Also, I'll stop comment about this.

Answer (score 37):

The reason this is impossible is that Java implements its Generics purely on the compiler level, and there is only one class file generated for each class.
This is called [Type Erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

At runtime, the compiled class needs to handle all of its uses with the same bytecode. So, `new T[capacity]` would have absolutely no idea what type needs to be instantiated.

Answer (score 21):

The answer was already given but if you already have an Instance of T then you can do this:

```
T t; //Assuming you already have this object instantiated or given by parameter.
int length;
T[] ts = (T[]) Array.newInstance(t.getClass(), length);
```

Hope, I could Help,
Ferdi265

Comment: This is a nice solution. But this will get unchecked warnings (cast from Object to T[]). Another "slower" but "warning-free" solution would be: `T[] ts = t.clone(); for (int i=0; i<ts.length; i++) ts[i] = null;`.

Comment: In addition, if what we kept is `T[] t`, then it would be `(T[]) Array.newInstance(t.getClass().getComponentType(), length);`. i did spend some times to figure out `getComponentType()`. Hope this helps others.

Comment: @midnite `t.clone()` will not return `T[]`. Because `t` is not Array in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

The main reason is due to the fact that arrays in Java are covariant.

There's a good overview [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255.html).

Comment: I don't see how you could support "new T[5]" even with invariant arrays.

Comment: @DimitrisAndreou Well, the whole thing is rather a comedy of errors in the Java design. It all started with array covariance. Then, once you have array covariance, you can cast `String[]` to `Object` and store an `Integer` in it. So then they had to add a runtime type check for array stores (`ArrayStoreException`) because the issue could not be caught at compile-time. (Otherwise, an `Integer` actually could be stuck in a `String[]`, and you would get an error when you tried to retrieve it, which would be horrible.) ...

Comment: @DimitrisAndreou … Then, once you have put a runtime check in place of a far sounder compile-time check, you run into type erasure (also an unfortunate design flaw -- included only for backward compatibility). Type erasure means that you _can't_ do runtime type checks for generic types. So therefore, to avoid the array storage type problem, you simply can't have generic arrays. If they had simply made arrays invariant in the first place, we could just do compile-time type checks without running afoul of erasure.

Comment: … I have just discovered the five-minute editing period for comments. `Object` should have been `Object[]` in my first comment.

Answer (score 3):

I like the answer indirectly given
by [Gafter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java/2927427#2927427).  However, I propose it is wrong.  I changed Gafter's code a little.  It compiles and it runs for a while then it bombs where Gafter predicted it would

```
class Box<T> {

    final T x;

    Box(T x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

class Loophole {

    public static <T> T[] array(final T... values) {
        return (values);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Box<String> a = new Box("Hello");
        Box<String> b = new Box("World");
        Box<String> c = new Box("!!!!!!!!!!!");
        Box<String>[] bsa = array(a, b, c);
        System.out.println("I created an array of generics.");

        Object[] oa = bsa;
        oa[0] = new Box<Integer>(3);
        System.out.println("error not caught by array store check");

        try {
            String s = bsa[0].x;
        } catch (ClassCastException cause) {
            System.out.println("BOOM!");
            cause.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
I created an array of generics.
error not caught by array store check
BOOM!
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at Loophole.main(Box.java:26)
```

So it appears to me you can create generic array types in java.  Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Your example is different from what I've asked. What you described are the dangers of array covariance. Check it out (for .NET : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx )

Comment: Hopefully you get a type-safety warning from the compiler, yes?

Comment: Yes, I get a type-safety warning.

Yes, I see that my example is not responsive to the question.

Comment: Actually you get multiple warnings due to sloppy initialization of a,b,c. Also, this is well known and affects the core library, e.g. <T>java.util.Arrays.asList(T...). If you pass any non-reifiable type for T, you get a warning (because the created array has a less precise type than the code pretends), and it's super ugly. It would be better if *the author* of this method got the warning, instead of emitting it at usage site, given that the method itself is safe, it doesn't expose the array to the user.

Comment: You did not create a generic array here. The compiler created a (non-generic) array for you.

Comment: For a second, i was reassuring myself what I am seeing couldn't be possible....but anyway self realisation kicks in....for future readers...the array store exception did not occur because after type erasure you could see that the underlying array is plain Box[] and the data you stored into box array was Box in both cases...ie the generics were to instruct the content of box(members) to be of specified type but not the box itself(class)....so as I said in the first array of boxes had boxes instance, then you casted the array into object type(covariant) and again assigned box type...

Comment: If only you had assigned a non box type to covariant Object[] array using object array reference ex: oa[0] = new String("different object"); then you would have got an array store exception....

Comment: Why did u get a type cast exception eventually? It is because you earlier instructed using generics at compile time that your bsa[] array was of generic type String since arrays are covariant the compiler which looked at the generics assumes you will always store Strings into that array. Hence when accessing bsa[0].x didn't warrant for a compilation error.

Comment: But what you actually did was you tricked the compiler into a fool by re-assigning the array reference to it's super type Object[] and exploited the fact that object array can hold all its subtype object behind the back of compiler. So compiler couldn't verify this and assumed you are still trying to access the string type which it assumed you stored earlier....

Comment: All these are compile time validation and hence these tricks actually bypassed compiler validation....but at runtime...when actual instances are being validated....by RTTI or runtime type info checker ....you get caught that the assignment was invalid since String reference can't really hold an Integer instance....Hence the CLASS CAST EXCEPTION

Comment: Very interesting fact is THIS CODE HERE MIGHT SEEM YOU CREATED A GENERIC ARRAY, but what you actually did was to create an Array of Box which internally holds generic items, as op said,

Comment: A generic array is something like T[] arr = new T[10]; but this is IMPOSSIBLE still as of java 11, because due to TYPE ERASURE the type T is erased at compile time and only base type Object remains at runtime....so if the T generic type was assigned to various types such as Integer, String, Double etc....then at compile time there needs to be separate classes for all those types....this is how it is done in C++ templates....

Comment: But in java only one base class is present and it is the generic type info erased class ex: <T> erases to type Object, <T extends Number> erases to type Number....also by rules of class hierarchy, covariance, upcasting doesn't require an explicit cast....this is the reason erasure works without casts....

Comment: On the other hand downcasting from higher type to lower type requires explicit cast since we wouldn't be sure which exact class or instance we are looking at, ex: custom class X in far future might extend Object, might not be known to the compiler beforehand, hence it forcefully asks for an explicit type cast.

Comment: The same is what compiler does in the name of type erasure, erases the generic info and keeps the base type...then creates appropriate explicit casts in the byte code since it knows what generic type the src/tgt reference/instances resolve into....based on its current inference over entire code which uses this generics....

Comment: BUT very important thing to NOTE is that IT IS NOT THE COMPILER WHICH CREATES THE INSTANCES IN HEAP but the RUNTIME engine or java VM which creates the instances hence for it to do a generic instantiation of objects it requires this info at runtime evaluation. But all it has is the Base type Object for generic type T at runtime....hence it creates Instance of Object type....

Comment: Now you could ask WHY NOT THE COMPILER THEN JUST INTRODUCE THE GENERIC TYPE CAST (T) by itself for the newly created Object instance?.....The ANSWER is the Object instance is half baked state of any subtype...ie we can get object(simple type) from say string(complex type) instance but getting string(complex) from an half baked or incomplete simple type Object is IMPOSSIBLE.... because Object doesn't even know it has a successor called String but a very complex type than Object...

Comment: This concludes the fact that any subtype instance cannot be recreated from base type and the only info after type erasure at runtime is the base type....

Comment: Don't forget that if instead of base type the compiler was instructed to create real generic object/instances by substituting the Generic class name, it would then mean the same generic class can no more be re-used by other sections of code wich specifies different generic type....if  the compiler did that then it would be overwriting the Type of object to be instantiated in the byte code for each new encounter of generic type assignment of same class.....AS I SAID EARLIER, THIS IS HOW C++ TACKLES IT, by having many copies of same TEMPLATE CLASS FOR DIFFERENT generic/template type invocation.

Comment: In C++ this leads to code duplication at compile time and at runtime there are many flavors of class types to choose from for same template class....

Comment: Java generics is good, but using it must come with proper knowledge....ex: T arr = (T) new Object; and T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[size]; (explicit casting) are due to above mentioned reasons...

Comment: NOTE: a generic type <T> is as much useless than just specifying Object as base type for reference when used in arrays(actual objects/instances must of target type T ex: String) coz both require explicit type cast when retrieving data from the container...

Comment: Another interesting fact is for ARRAYS, Java generics allows <T extends Number> T[] arr; ie, ALLOWS EXTENDS because of the COVARIANT nature but DENIES SUPER (<T super Number>) because for <T extends Number> the container will surely contain subtypes only which do not require cast when writing into container(this is allowed since subtypes contain atleast base type info + additional info)..on the other hand <T super Number> is not allowed, since supertype ex: (incomplete or simple) Object instance cannot be interpreted as Number (subtype) anytime..not enough info about subtype is present in base

Comment: As for Java Collections, the language designers must have thought that by restricting more, the Heap pollution caused by covariance of array could be avoided, hence no more ArrayStoreException... The only change required was to make Collections Invariant, ie covariance of array is disallowed....ex array of Animal could contain cat, dog, etc but List of Animal must contain only animals and not subtypes such as cats dogs or supertypes of Animal...

Comment: The Invariance property is however not much useful, hence to bring back the covariance property for subtype relationship <T extends U> or <? extends U> was required in this case subtype T instances can be assigned to base type U without a cast. Similarly additional property of contravariance for supertype relationship <T super U> or <? super> was introduced....

Comment: A List<T super Cat> might have Zoo, Animals,...down until Cat...A List<T extends Zoo> might have Cat, Animal...up until Zoo. For 'extends' we can minimum guarantee it might be up-until zoo(supertype of T) since T must be constructed only after Zoo is constructed. For 'super' we can maximum guarantee we can only insert new types down-until Cat and not any lower than that.

Comment: Based on the fact that any subtype has its supertype as a part of itself, subtype to supertype doesn't require explicit casting...This same fact is used for both extends/super.

Comment: Just that the bounds are different for 'extends'... upper bound is U and Lowe bound is T....so any T can atleast DISPLAY its internal U ..... similarly for 'super'...upper bound is T and lower bound is U...so any T can ACCEPT U because it must atleast contain T.

Comment: Following this, PECS (Producer(Output - U to T) Extends and Consumer(Input - T to U) Super) from/to a collection respectively is used for generics variance definition.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I simply wanted an array of stacks, something like this:

```
Stack<SomeType>[] stacks = new Stack<SomeType>[2];
```

Since this was not possible, I used the following as a workaround:

1. Created a non-generic wrapper class around Stack (say MyStack)
2. MyStack[] stacks = new MyStack[2] worked perfectly well

Ugly, but Java is happy.

Note: as mentioned by BrainSlugs83 in the comment to the question, it is totally possible to have arrays of generics in .NET

Answer (score 3):

From [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays):

> You cannot create arrays of parameterized types. For example, the following code does not compile:
>
> ```
> List<Integer>[] arrayOfLists = new List<Integer>[2];  // compile-time error
> ```
>
> The following code illustrates what happens when different types are inserted into an array:
>
> ```
> Object[] strings = new String[2];
> strings[0] = "hi";   // OK
> strings[1] = 100;    // An ArrayStoreException is thrown.
> ```
>
> If you try the same thing with a generic list, there would be a problem:
>
> ```
> Object[] stringLists = new List<String>[];  // compiler error, but pretend it's allowed
> stringLists[0] = new ArrayList<String>();   // OK
> stringLists[1] = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // An ArrayStoreException should be thrown,
>                                             // but the runtime can't detect it.
> ```
>
> If arrays of parameterized lists were allowed, the previous code would fail to throw the desired ArrayStoreException.

To me, it sounds very weak. I think that anybody with a sufficient understanding of generics, would be perfectly fine, and even expect, that the ArrayStoredException is not thrown in such case.

Comment: This is true that genericized arrays cannot be created not due to the fact that type erasure is in place...since the types are erased at compile time, new instantiation of List class is possible only without its generic type...hence

Comment: how can one allow such usage...one way would be to stop doing type erasure + retain different versions of the class byte code for different generic types as in C++ templates....then the above syntax of genericized array instantiation is completely valid............List<Integer>[] arrayOfLists = new List[2];  // is completely valid since the List interface itself is the only things that remains after generic paramter type info is erased by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

class can declare an array of type T[], but it cannot directly instantiate such an array. Instead, a common approach is to instantiate an array of type Object[], and then make a narrowing cast to type T[], as shown in the following:

```
  public class Portfolio<T> {
  T[] data;
 public Portfolio(int capacity) {
   data = new T[capacity];                 // illegal; compiler error
   data = (T[]) new Object[capacity];      // legal, but compiler warning
 }
 public T get(int index) { return data[index]; }
 public void set(int index, T element) { data[index] = element; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because generics were added on to java after they made it, so its kinda clunky because the original makers of java thought that when making an array the type would be specified in the making of it. So that does not work with generics so you have to do 
E[] array=(E[]) new Object[15];
This compiles but it gives a warning.

Answer (score 0):

There surely must be a good way around it (maybe using reflection), because it seems to me that that's exactly what `ArrayList.toArray(T[] a)` does. I quote:

> `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`
>
> Returns an array containing all of the
>   elements in this list in the correct order; the runtime type of the
>   returned array is that of the specified array. If the list fits in the
>   specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is
>   allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of
>   this list.

So one way around it would be to use this function i.e. create an `ArrayList` of the objects you want in the array, then use `toArray(T[] a)` to create the actual array. It wouldn't be speedy, but you didn't mention your requirements.

So does anyone know how `toArray(T[] a)` is implemented?

Comment: List.toArray(T[]) works because you are essentially giving it the component type T at runtime (you are giving it an instance of the desired array type, from which it can get the array class, and then, the component class T). With the actual component type at runtime, you can always create an array of that runtime type using `Array.newInstance()`. You'll find that mentioned in many question that ask how to create an array with a type unknown at compile time. But the OP was specifically asking *why* you can't use the `new T[]` syntax, which is a different question

Answer (score 0):

If we cannot instantiate generic arrays, why does the language have generic array types? What's the point of having a type without objects?

The only reason I can think of, is varargs - `foo(T...)`. Otherwise they could have completely scrubbed generic array types. (Well, they didn't really have to use array for varargs, since varargs didn't exist before *1.5*. That's probably another mistake.)

So it is a lie, you *can* instantiate generic arrays, through varargs!

Of course, the problems with generic arrays are still real, e.g.

```
static <T> T[] foo(T... args){
    return args;
}
static <T> T[] foo2(T a1, T a2){
    return foo(a1, a2);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] x2 = foo2("a", "b"); // heap pollution!
}
```

We can use this example to actually demonstrate the danger of *generic* array.

On the other hand, we've been using generic varargs for a decade, and the sky is not falling yet. So we can argue that the problems are being exaggerated; it is not a big deal. If explicit generic array creation is allowed, we'll have bugs here and there; but we've been used to the problems of erasure, and we can live with it.

And we can point to `foo2` to refute the claim that the spec keeps us from the problems that they claim to keep us from. If Sun had more time and resources for *1.5*, I believe they could have reached a more satisfying resolution.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, you can of course create via [some tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/530289/2361308).

**But it's not recommended.**

Because the [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and more importantly the `covariance` in array which just allows a subtype array can be assigned to a supertype array, which forces you to use explicit type cast when trying to get the value back causing run-time `ClassCastException` which is one of the main objectives that generics try to eliminate: [Stronger type checks at compile time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

```
Object[] stringArray = { "hi", "me" };
stringArray[1] = 1;
String aString = (String) stringArray[1]; // boom! the TypeCastException
```

A more direct example can found in [Effective Java: Item 25](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=effective%20java%20generic%20array&source=bl&ots=yXJkRio4P3&sig=FQRL3NynZZzobBmx5Jn1AHDiVcM&hl=en&ei=alMNTNfZC5G2Nry-yaAK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).

---

*covariance*: an array of type S[] is a subtype of T[] if S is a subtype of T

Answer (score 0):

T vals[]; // OK

But, you cannot instantiate an array of T
// vals = new T[10]; // can't create an array of T

The reason you can’t create an array of T is that there is no way for the
compiler to know what type of array to actually create.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
List<?>[] arrayOfLists = new List<?>[4];
```

Comment: This actually works and does not throw any compile time errors. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: @AdityaMayukhSom
Also `List[] array = new List[4]` would work, because "List" is reifiable. That is, it's a "real" type at runtime even after erasure.

Per [JLS 15.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10) the type in an array creation expression must be "reifiable."
Per [JLS 4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7) a type may be reifiable if type parameters are wildcards.
The wildcards mean you don't know what it's a List of, limiting what you can do to safe operations the same way raw types do.