# How to create an array of a collection?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the reason I can’t create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java)

```
HashSet<Integer>[] rows = new HashSet<Integer>[9];
```

gives me a compilation error: generic array creation.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java

Comment: Best Answer on that dup that pertains to answering this question more specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33072474/1357094

Comment: Still worth asking this as the other Question uses generic variable type `T` (not a concrete Class as here).

Comment: Surprising now one mentioned this solution ::  Set<Integer>[] list = new Set[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    list[i] = new HashSet<>();

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The simple answer: **do not mix arrays with generics!**

Use a list of hashsets:

```
ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> rows = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>();
```

The problem here is that Java specification doesn't allow you to declare an array of generics object.

A workaround of it is to use the wildcard, but you will lose the type-safety:

```
HashSet<?>[] rows = new HashSet<?>[9];

for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i)
    rows[i] = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

This, in your case, won't create problems when you are going to check if an item is contained: you can easily do `rows[0].contains(4)` but when adding new content you will be forced to cast the row to the right type and suppress the warning of unchecked cast itself:

```
((HashSet<Integer>)rows[0]).add(4);
```

A side note: if you feel pioneer just download the [Trove Collections](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net) framework that has a not-generics, highly optimized version of an **integer hashset** made to work with primitive type, I'm talking about the [`TIntHashSet`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TIntHashSet.html) class: it will solve your problem and you'll end up having faster code.

Comment: I am not mixing arrays with generics. How about HashSet[] rows = new HashSet[9]?

Comment: @wizard@: Yes you are (he means "don't mix them together", not "don't confuse one for the other.")  If they are untyped, you'll just get raw-type warnings instead.  That's no more correct.

Comment: I liked your original answer better.

Comment: By declaring `rows` as `HashSet<?>` you are loosing all of the compile time checking you would get from having a generic typed declaration; at the expense of 'fixing' a single compiler warning.  Its cast once (with a warning) or cast everywhere.

Comment: Actually I wouldn't never ever suggest to apply my solution. Since you shouldn't mix arrays and generics, that's all.. it was just for trivia :)

Comment: how to display the element for array of set?

Answer (score 7):

You can declare the generic on the type declaration, but not when you actually allocate the object.  Not sure the exact reason, perhaps to re-enforce the concept that some generics information is not preserved at compile time.

```
Set<Integer> rows[] = new HashSet[3];
for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
 rows[i] = new HashSet<Integer>();
}
```

Comment: That both doesn't compile and gives warnings anyhow.  To demonstrate the actual problem you would need to typecast rows to an `Object[]`, like `Object[] rows2 = rows`, noting that that doesn't generate a warning.

Comment: I had a typeo, my original test used string.

Answer (score 7):

To quote Effective Java Second edition by Joshua Bloch, page 119

> Because of these fundamental
>   differences, arrays and generics do
>   not mix well. For example, it is
>   illegal to create an array of a
>   generic type, a parameterized type, or
>   a type parameter. None of these array
>   creation expressions are legal: `new
>   List<E>[], new List<String>[], new
>   E[]`. All will result in *generic array
>   creation* errors at compile time.
>
> Why is it illegal to create a generic
>   array? Because it isn’t typesafe. If
>   it were legal, casts generated by the
>   compiler in an otherwise correct
>   program could fail at runtime with a
>   `ClassCastException`. This would violate
>   the fundamental guarantee provided by
>   the generic type system.

(I omitted the part that explains Generic type erasure)

The Generics chapter of this book is [available as a PDF](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Any time you're chaining generics or nesting data structures like this, it's time to take a step back and think about what you're really trying to do.

Would this be better if it were encapsulated in a wrapper class? It will probably make things less complex later. A week from now when you have to debug something in your array of hashsets of arraylists of arrays of some simple datatype because you thought you'd just keep wrapping them, you'll be sorry.

-edit: arrays are illegal? Point noted. I still feel the argument here stands.

You're using Java; don't be afraid to make some extra classes.

```
public class MyIntegers {
    private HashSet<Integer> theIntegers;

    // wrap methods
    public boolean add(Integer i) { return theIntegers.add(i); }
    public boolean contains(Integer i)...
    public boolean remove(Integer i)...

}

// later...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyIntegers[] rows = new MyIntegers[NUM_ROWS];
}
```

Comment: I like this answer much better. I was also just having this problem and tearing my hair out trying to get <?> to work with all the casting. I also tried nesting arraylists, but then you lose the nice [x] access, and have to call .get(x) instead. And sometimes installing add-ons isn't an option.