# How to make a List that holds an ArrayList /LinkedList of a specific type at each element?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, 2d

so I need to create an Array of length 10,000. However, this array must hold an array list / linked list of a specific type at each element. I tried everything but I seem to be extremely clueless about the syntax.

Thanks for your time.

the problem im trying to solve: (i just cant understand what arrays i need to have =/)

In this problem, you will have to implement MapCMPS data structure. MapCMPS maps a key to a value (key and value 
are considered a pair). MapCMPS cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value. If you add a 
duplicate key, the latest add should be ignored. Your MapCMPS data structure must support an efficient search for a 
value given its key. For this, it should be implemented internally as an array of 10000 list, i.e., each element of the array 
can hold a list of elements (of type Pair). Then, the operations provided by the map can be implemented as follows:

1. put(key, value): this method adds (key, value) pair to the MapCMPS. Internally, you are to compute a positive
   index 0 = i < 10000 from the input key, then you insert the pair (key, value) to the array at that index. As such, 
   when you want to search for a value where its key has an index i, you can only restrict your search to the 
   elements at the index i of the array. Note that, the Object class has a hashCode method that returns an integer. 
   Hence, the index of a key object can be the hashCode value modulo 10000. To support keys of custom type, you 
   should consider overriding the hashCode method to return an integer given the fields of the key type. For 
   instance, if you have a class Point with two fields x and y, you may return the absolute value of their sum.
2. get(key): this method must return the value that corresponds to the input key. If the input key does not exist in 
   the map, you should throw ElementNotFoundException exception. To do so, you can benefit from the 
   implementation of the put method. That is, instead of searching the key in all the lists of the arrays, you should
   restrict your search to only the elements of the of the array at the index that corresponds to the hashing of the 
   input key.
3. containsKey(key): this method returns true if the map contains the given key, and false otherwise.

public class MapCMPS{

```
private ArrayList list = new ArrayList(10000);
public MapCMPS(){
    for(int i = 0; i <10000; i++){
        list[i] = ArrayList<Pair> a = new ArrayList();
    }
}



public void put(int key, int value){

    Pair pair = new Pair(key, value);
    int index = pair.hashCode();

    list[i].a.add(pair);

}
```

}

thats what i have and i dont know how to carry on :/

Comment: Could this question be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in disguise? You may wish to consider telling us more of the details of the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it. For one thing, I'm not sure what you mean by "a specific type at each element", and perhaps you want to create a `List<MyCustomType>` where each list item is an object of your custom class, containing data held in several fields, but again, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: When you say "of a specific type at each elemen", what do you mean - that element 0 is a `List<Integer>`, element 1 is a `List<String>` etc? Because you can't do this in a type-safe way if your outer container is a list.

Comment: Post what you've tried so far with the specific problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an array of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992615/how-to-create-an-array-of-a-collection)

Comment: for this to make sense u must read the entire problem.... ill edit my post

Comment: Please put in the effort to format your question. It is not easy to read at present.

Comment: thanks for the edit Hover

Comment: Given the edit to the question, I still vote this as a duplicate. The context of the entire problem helped explain what he wanted, but doesn't change what I suggested as the duplicate.

Comment: Mohammad: you still should show some reasonable attempt with your question and use it to make the question more specific.

Comment: i cant find what i need in other questions since i cant understand the current case Im working with atm im sry

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels I don;t know how to approach the problem like i still can't understand what should the array of length 10,000 contain... =/ i was hoping someone could clarify what is needed

Comment: if someone can help me understand what arrays i need to create i can do the entire thing

Comment: Your code is implementing the way I was reading the problem. However, you can remove the `ArrayList<Pair> a` assignment.

Alternatively, you can just do `ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair>> = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair>>(10000);`

Comment: okay any ideas how i can add a pair to a specific index in the first array and then to the array list within the index?

Comment: `list.get(indexOfOuterList).add(indexOfEmbeddedList, element);`

This gets the list at the index you want, and then you can add an element at the specified index of the inner list, if that's what you mean. Try going from there and make sure you understand what the problem is asking. If you have more questions, I suggest making clear, concise separate questions on SO for them. Make sure to read the guidelines. Extended comments are discouraged.