# HashTable generic array creation error

Tags: java

This is a grade 12 java HashTable assignment.

So my teacher gave me the template for doing this assignment, but it does not work :(. And he expects us to get the template to work and then do the assignment.

Here's what he gave us:

```
class MyHashTable<T>{
    private T[] vals;
    private int load;
    public MyHashTable(){
        load = 0;
        vals = new T[10];
    }
    public MyHashTable(int size){
        load = 0;
        vals = new T[size];
    }
    public void add(T obj){//don't care about negatives
        int size = vals.length;
        if((load+1.0)/size>0.6){
            size*=10;
            T[] tmp = new T[size];
            for(int i=0;i<size/10;i++){
                if(vals[i]!=null){
                    add(vals[i], tmp);
                }
            }
            vals = tmp;
        }
        add(obj, vals);
    }
    public void add(T obj, T[]vals){
        int loc = Math.abs(obj.hashCode())%vals.length;
        while(vals[loc]!=null){
            loc = (loc+1)%vals.length;
        }
        vals[loc] = obj;
    }
    /*public boolean contains(T obj){

    } */
}
```

it gives an error:   error: generic array creation

Can anyone tell me what does that mean? With examples hopefully.

Comment: Due to type erasure, you cannot create instances of type parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everybody said generic type is erased at runtime:

- `T` becomes `Object`,
- `T extends SomeClass` becomes `SomeClass`.

So you have at least two options

1. You can use same pattern that was used in `ArrayList<T>` and store items in `Object[]` array rather then `T[]` array

   ```
   vals = (T[]) new Object[size];
   ```
2. If you want to create array of real `T` type you would have to make user to pass instance of `Class<T>` object that will correspond `T` and use it like

   ```
   vals = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazzT, size);
   ```

where clazzT is `Class<T>` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way that generics are implemented in Java, it is not possible to use generics such that type information is needed at runtime. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 2):

> error: generic array creation

You can not create arrays from generic types.

See also [What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java)