# Java Generic Classes Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, class, generics

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2927427/1151151), and now got confused about the normal array declaration and this piece of code used to create arrays for generic classes:

```
Gen<?> gens[] = new Gen<?>[10];
```

What does this do exactly, and how it is different from the normal array declaration?

Comment: Take a look at this great Q&A simple and short tutorial: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm only a beginner so I might be wrong, but this is my take on the declaration you've written:

Gen is a generic class, like a template. The question mark signifies a wildcard. Therefore, you have initialized an array of 10 Gen templates that may be configured with any type of object.

Answer (score 2):

it is an array with 10 places that holds a generic class of type Gen that is a generic class of any object