# How can I put a hashmap inside an array? conf[0] = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

How can I put a hashmap inside an array?

```
HashMap<String, Object>[] config= null;
        config[0] = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
        config[0].put("Name", "Jon");
        config[0].put("valueA", 0);
        config[1] = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
        config[1].put("valueA", 2323);
```

Comment: This is Array of HashMaps, And you have to initialized array with some size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Map<String, String>[]> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>[]>();
```

should be sufficient.  You don't instantiate it with the `()` since it is an array, you need to provide it a size or a series of `HashMap`s as part of the array constructor.

Comment: Thanks you! But How Can I do this without provide a size? Is it possible?
if I use your code I get the following error:
"Cannot create a generic array of HashMap<String,Object>"

Comment: I see :) I'll remove my comment

Comment: @Heuster it was my mistake, gotta stop trusting my memory :)

Comment: Why make it a List of Map arrays? Why not just a List of Maps?

Comment: @TomMcIntyre because OP wants it to be an array

Answer (score 1):

You can find some explanation here [What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java)

I propose to use next construction:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> config= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> map;
map = new HashMap<String, Object>();        
map.put("Name", "Jon");
map.put("valueA", 0);       
config.add(map); 
map = new HashMap<String, Object>();        
map.put("valueA", 2323);                        
config.add(map);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's works! And for read: `config.get(0).get("Name"); //Jon` edit/add: `config.get(0).put("Name", "Snow"));`

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can declare an array of generics, you cannot instantiate them using the normal syntax.

`Map<String,Object>[] config = new HashMap<String,Object>[10];` would give the compile error: 
Cannot create a generic array of HashMap

You can however use `Array.newInstance` [see answers to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Answer (score 0):

use ArrayList  instead of a simple array.

```
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayOfMap=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
```

Comment: why we put '0' at end of some HashMap ?
ex :
'new hashmap<>(0);' why we not use 'new hashmap<>();'

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,Object>[] config = new HashMap[10];
```

just leave the generic parameters away.