# Generic multi dimensional array conversion function

Tags: java, arrays, generics, multidimensional-array

This function converts a 2-dimensional `Collection` of `String`s to a 2-dimensional array of `String`s:

```
public static String[][] toArray(
                             Collection<? extends Collection<String>> values){

    String[][] result = new String[ values.size() ][];
    int i=0;
    for( Collection<String> row : values ){
        result[i] = row.toArray( new String[ row.size() ] );
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

How would this function be written in order to do this generically:

```
public static <X> X[][] ArrayArray(Collection<? extends Collection<X>> values){
    // ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics and arrays don't mix. One alternative is to pass a `Class` instance representing `X` and use that to create the return array (see [`Array.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29)). I believe a better approach would be to pass an `X[][]` in as another argument, fill it, and return it:

```
public static <X> X[][] toArray(Collection<? extends Collection<X>> values,
        X[][] result) {

    int i = 0;
    for (Collection<X> row : values)
        result[i] = row.toArray(result[i++]);

    return result;
}
```

---

For example:

```
List<List<Integer>> l = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3), 
                                      Arrays.asList(4,5),
                                      Arrays.asList(6));

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(toArray(l, new Integer[l.size()][0])));
```

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Your missing "result[i] =" in your code. And in the example you don't need to specify the second dimension: "new Integer[2][]" is good. But this solution misses (at least my) point of having this function. I don't want to create the array in advance.

Comment: @Scheintod You do need the second dimension, and you don't need `result[i] =` if the array is appropriately sized. If you don't want to create the array you can 1) return an `Object[][]` or 2) use the `Class` approach that I described.

Comment: ah. sorry. missed the (result[i++]) part because I haven't used it this way. In my opinion this cries "hard to find errors". Because if you specify it to small you won't get any warnings but no result.

Comment: @Scheintod You can easily add a check for that, `result.length == values.size()`. The idea remains the same.

Comment: Ah. Difficult to follow the edits :) Thank you. I will mark this as correct. For me mainly because of the reference to Arrays.newInstance with which I can figure it out for myself. But for reference this would be the more "interessting" solution (hint ;)).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't.

> It's because Java's arrays (unlike generics) contain, at runtime, information about its component type. So you must know the component type when you create the array. Since you don't know what T is at runtime, you can't create the array

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2931240, by [newacct](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86989/newacct)

Comment: Technically this is the most correct answer to my question. But it's the least helpful.

Comment: (: true... but you can't respect the interface you proposed and solve your problem. I thought you needed to honor it, that's why I didn't post any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

So it's not possible because of type erasure. But there is at least a solution for:

```
public static <X> X[][] toArray( Class<X> xClass, 
        Collection<? extends Collection<X>> values ){

    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    X[][] result = (X[][])Array.newInstance( xClass , values.size(), 0 );

    int i=0;
    for( Collection<X> row : values ){

        @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
        X[] rowAsArray = (X[])Array.newInstance( xClass, row.size() );
        result[i] = row.toArray( rowAsArray );
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

(thanks for pointing me to `Array.newInstance`)