# How to create an array with Iterable elements in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, iterable

I want to create an array which its length is **fixed**, but the elements are reference to `Iterable` objects. Just like creating an array with pointer elements in C, where the pointers can point to lists of any length.

I tried this:

```
// declaration
private Iterable<String>[] a;
...
// in construtor, n is known length.
a = (Iterable<String>[]) new Object[n];
```

The compiler gives me a warning. And when I execute the program. the exception below is thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Iterable;
```

I searched through the web. But the results are all **dynamic array** but not **fixed-length array with dynamic elements**. Thanks a lot if you can help!

**UPDATE**

I'll try to put it simpler. What I want is like an **array of references**, and the reference can point to some Iterable object.

Comment: Did you read what it says? You cannot cast an Object to an Iterable.

Comment: Why you don't use ArrayList ? It take less effort but more effective.

Comment: if you want to guarantee the size is always constant and still use an iterable, you might first create a normal array and convert it to a list to use iterable over it (e.g Arrays(a).asList) hoping you know what you are doing

Comment: If you want to enforce fixed-length beyond creation time, you can use FixedSizeList from the Commons library.

Comment: @TienNguyen I tried `ArrayList`, in which I declare like this `private ArrayList<Queue<String>> a`. But after I initialize it with a initial count 4, and trying to add a queue into index 3, an exception is thrown.

Comment: @hichris123 Yes, I know it, but Java doesn't allow generic array neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you really do want an array whose elements are `Iterable<String>`, so I won't tell you to use a different data structure. (Though that might be a good idea.)

You're running squarely into a terrible mismatch in Java between arrays and generics.

As you discovered, `Object[]` is not compatible with `Iterable<String>[]`. So as a first attempt you could try to create an array of `Iterable`:

```
Iterable<String>[] a = new Iterable[n];
```

This will give you a "rawtypes" warning. You then might try to create a generic array like this:

```
Iterable<String>[] a = new Iterable<String>[n]; // ERROR
```

but this gives a compiler error, "generic array creation." See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java) for the reason why. Briefly, the reason is that generics are generally erased and arrays are reified. The only reified generic type is the unbounded wildcard `<?>`, so you have to create an array of this type and cast it:

```
Iterable<String>[] a = (Iterable<String>[])new Iterable<?>[n];
```

Now this gives you an unchecked warning. This is unavoidable, so you have to suppress it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Iterable<String>[] a = (Iterable<String>[])new Iterable<?>[n];
```

So that's what you have to do to create an array of a generic type.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you need to use something like this:-

ArrayList<Iterable<String>> temp = new ArrayList<Iterable<String>>();
        Iterable<String> ob1=new Iterable<String>(){

            @Override
            public Iterator<String> iterator() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return new ArrayList<String>().iterator();
            }

        };
        temp.add(ob1);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but when initializing it with count 4, and trying to add a Iterable object like queue into index 3, an exception is thrown.

Comment: ArrayList grows dynamically, what kind of exception is thrown?

Comment: As you say, it just grows dynamically. The exception is `IndexOutOfBounds` with a hint that `Size is 0, index is 3`. It seems that even if I initialize it with 4, I cannot add into index 3 at first, meaning that I cannot access it just like an array.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code given below. you dont have to create Object array rather an iterable array

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Iterable<String>[] iterableArr;//array definition
        //Java doesn't allow creation of generic type array (e.g. new Iterable<String>[]), 
        //so you can create a raw type array (e.g. new Iterable[2]). It generates compiler warning, which can be supressed.
        iterableArr = new Iterable[2];//array initialization

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); //Creating and adding list1 to iterableArr
        list1.add("1");
        list1.add("2");
        list1.add("3");
        iterableArr[0] = list1;

        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(); //Creating and adding list2 to iterableArr
        list2.add("A");
        list2.add("B");
        list2.add("C");
        iterableArr[1] = list2;

        //printing the data
        for (Iterable<String> iterable : iterableArr) {
            for (Iterator<String> iterator = iterable.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                String string = (String) iterator.next();
                System.out.print(string+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```