# Java creating a array of type generic

Tags: java

I have a generic K and wish to create an empty array so I type

```
private K[] keys   = new K[0];
```

However eclipse says "Cannot create an generic array of K"

Have I missed something? You can create an empty array of int, is this something generics can't do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create arrays of generics in Java. A workaround would be:

```
keys = (K[])new Object[size];
```

Although this will generate a compiler warning.

Generally, this is not a good practice and it is not safe to do it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java) thread for more.

However, if you just can't avoid it, it should only be used with `new` as this casting of an `Object` array to `K[]` might be used to insert stuff you won't like.

*Update*:

But really, as you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20557937/2568511) answer `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance()` is probably the safer way using the reflection library.

Comment: Would this be generally safe? Or will the cast and use of object potentially cause corner cases?

Comment: @Zimm3r You are right. It will probably not be. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What if `K` is abstract? How would the executor know how to fill any missing methods?

Also, due to type-erasure upon compilation, you can't tell what class `K` actually is without comparing it to others, which would require an instance.

[Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: An abstract `K` isn't a problem, any more than it's a problem to create a `List[]`. You can create an array of an abstract class (or interface), because the array doesn't need to know what its elements' implementations are.

Comment: @yshavit it was merely an example. The main concept is that there is information missing that isn't available.

Comment: Yes, but it has everything to do with erasure (which you linked to) and nothing to do with `K` potentially being abstract. That's all I was saying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Array.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) method to achieve something like this; consider

```
public class Question<K> {
  private K[] keys;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public Question(Class<? extends K> cls, int size) {
    this.keys = (K[]) Array.newInstance(cls, size);
  }

  public K[] getKeys() {
    return keys;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Question<String> question = new Question<String>(
        String.class, 10);
    String[] keys = question.getKeys();
    keys[0] = "Hello";
    keys[1] = "World";
    keys[2] = "Goodbye";
    keys[3] = "I must";
    keys[4] = "be Going";
    keys[5] = "Now";
    keys[6] = "Parting";
    keys[7] = "is";
    keys[8] = "such";
    keys[9] = "sweet sorrow";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(question
        .getKeys()));
  }
}
```

Here this prints

```
[Hello, World, Goodbye, I must, be Going, Now, Parting, is, such, sweet sorrow]
```

Comment: Pretty sure not allowed to use that. We are not allowed to use an of the builtin java storage classes. (Though I assume we can use array sense otherwise it would be rather hackish to deal with pointers etc).

Comment: This is using Java reflection to construct the object array. It's how you can do it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You are right, It can be done with `java.lang.reflect.Array` as well. In my answer I just thought that  `new K[size]` cannot be said in java, and the immediate workaround that came to mind :) This is definitely safer.