# Generic stack implementation

Tags: java, generics, stack

I'm trying to implement a generic stack.

Here's the interface

```
package stack;

public interface Stack<T>{
    void push(T number);
    T pop();
    T peek();
    boolean isEmpty();
    boolean isFull();
}
```

Here's the class

```
package stack;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class StackArray <T> implements Stack<T>{
    private int maxSize;
    private T[] array;
    private int top;

    public StackArray(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
//        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        this.array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(StackArray.class, maxSize);
        this.top = -1;
    }

    private T[] resizeArray() {
        /**
         * create a new array double the size of the old, copy the old elements then return the new array */
        int newSize = maxSize * 2;
        T[] newArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(StackArray.class, newSize);
        for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
            newArray[i] = this.array[i];
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return top == -1;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return top == maxSize-1;
    }

    public void push(T element) {
        if(!this.isFull()) {
            ++top;
            array[top] = element;
        }
        else {
            this.array = resizeArray();
            array[++top] = element;
        }
    }

    public T pop() {
        if(!this.isEmpty())
            return array[top--];
        else {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
    }

    public T peek() {
        return array[top];
    }
}
```

Here's the Main class

```
package stack;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "Hello World!";
        Stack <Character>stack = new StackArray<>(word.length());

//        for(Character ch : word.toCharArray()) {
//            stack.push(ch);
//        }

        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            stack.push(word.toCharArray()[i]);
        }

        String reversedWord = "";
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            char ch = (char) stack.pop();
            reversedWord += ch;
        }
        System.out.println(reversedWord);

    }
}
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Character
    at stack.StackArray.push(StackArray.java:40)
    at stack.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

line 40 is in the push method

```
        array[top] = element;
```

*Side Question:
Any way to suppress the warning in the constructor? :)*

Comment: Didn't you want write T[] array = new T[maxsize]; instead of  (T[]) Array.newInstance(StackArray.class, maxSize); ?

Comment: `Array.newInstance(StackArray.class, maxSize);` will create an Array for `StackArray` elements. You're trying to put a `Character` in that array and that is not possible.

Comment: please take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/q/20557762/814304

Comment: Use of `newInstance` is the fundamental issue. Just declare an `Object[]` and use an unsafe `T[]` cast along with an `@SuppressWarnings` annotation, being sure to add the mandatory associated code comment explaining why it's safe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The underlying issue is type erasure. The relevant implications of this means that an instance of the `Stack` class doesn't know it's type arguments at run-time.  This is the reason why you can't just use the most natural solution here, `array = new T[maxSize]`.

You've tried to work around this by creating an array using `Array.newInstance(...)`, but unfortunately this array does not have elements of type `T` either.  In the code shown the elements are of type `StackArray`, which is probably not what you intended.

One common way of dealing with this is to use an array of `Object` internally to `Stack`, and cast any return values to type `T` in accessor methods.

```
class StackArray<T> implements Stack<T> {
    private int maxSize;
    private Object[] array;
    private int top;

    public StackArray(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.array = new Object[maxSize];
        this.top = -1;
    }

    // ... lines removed ...

    public T pop() {
        if(this.isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        return element(top--);
    }

    public T peek() {
        if(this.isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        return element(top);
    }

    // Safe because push(T) is type checked.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private T element(int index) {
        return (T)array[index];
    }
}
```

Note also you have a bug in the `resizeArray()` method where `maxSize` is never assigned a new value.  You don't really need to keep track of `maxSize`, as you could just use `array.length`.

I think there is also an issue with `peek()` when the stack is empty in the original code.

Comment: Thank you very for the extra bugs. As to the original problem, I'm never comfortable with using Object, so I kept the array as an array of T, but assigned an array of Object to it in the constructor (after casting) like @Lew Bloch suggested. Maybe it's the same thing tho:)

Answer (score 2):

Your code creates arrays of StackArray, and then you try to stick Character objects in it, just as if you were doing this:

```
static void add(Object arr[], Object o) {
    arr[0] = o;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackArray stack[] = new StackArray[1];
    Character c = 'x';
    add(stack, c);
}
```