# Initialize an Item Array

Tags: java, initialization, init

I want to initialize an Item Array but can't figure it out.

Here is my code.

```
public class HashTable<Item> {
private int m;          // hash table size
private Item[] T;       // hash table

HashTable(int M)
{
    m = M;
    T = new Item[M];
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        Item T[i] = null;
    }
}
...
...
```

***SOLUTION***

```
T = (Item[])new Object[M];
```

Comment: What would you achieve by explicitly initializing the array elements with their default value? The array elements are all already `null`.

Comment: `HashTable` is present in JDK as a class. Change the name. `T[i] = new Item();`

Comment: `Item T[i] = null;` or `T[i] = null;`?

Comment: Even if  remove the "for loop" still it says "Can not create a generic array of Item".

Comment: @STUDENT_LIFE So `Item` is a type parameter? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2927391/2040040

Comment: @johnchen902 Changed the code. Well I haven't create it anywhere. It is given to me with that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create the array of Generic type,Please look at this post.

[How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation)

Comment: I looked at these posts and I found someone saying: " T = (Item[])new Object[M]; " which worked. Just wrote it so someone else can see it.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need is something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
    T[i] = new Item(); // call some constructor here
}
```

You have

```
Item T[i] = ...
```

in your loop, while it should be just

```
T[i] = ...
```

So try these hints.

Also do this:

```
T = (Item[])new Object[M];
```

as Kumar suggested in his reply.

The thing is that Item is not really a type here. You need 
to read how generics are actually compiled into bytecode,
and you will see what happens under the hood.

Comment: That didn't help. I don't have to make a Item constructor. Check my code again.

Comment: @STUDENT_LIFE OK, I updated my answer so that it's not off topic. Great catch by Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created the class item you could call it like this:

```
public class HashTable
{
    private int tableSize;          // hash table size
    private Item[] table;       // hash table

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // where 10 is the number of nodes
        Item[] myTable = createHashTable(10);
    }

    private static Item[] createHashTable(int size)
    {
        Item[] table = new Item[size];

        for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
        {
            table[i] = new Item(i);
        }
    }
}
```

However if you want to see an example of a full HashTable implementation:

```
/*
 * HashTable.java
 *
 *
 */

/**
 * A class that implements a hash table that employs open addressing
 * using either linear probing, quadratic probing, or double hashing.
 */
public class HashTable {
    /* Private inner class for an entry in the hash table */
    private class Entry {
    private String key;
    private LLList valueList;        // all of the values with this key
    private boolean hasBeenRemoved;  // has this entry been removed?

    private Entry(String key, int value) {
        this.key = key;
        valueList = new LLList();
        valueList.addItem(value, 0);
        hasBeenRemoved = false;
    }
    }

    // parameters for the second hash function -- see h2() below
    private static final int H2_MIN = 5;
    private static final int H2_DIVISOR = 11;

    // possible types of probing
    public static final int LINEAR = 0;
    public static final int QUADRATIC = 1;
    public static final int DOUBLE_HASHING = 2;
    public static final int NUM_PROBE_TYPES = 3;

    private Entry[] table;             // the hash table itself
    private int probeType = LINEAR;    // the type of probing

    // keeps track of how many times we perform a probe of a given length
    private int[] probeLengthCount;

    public HashTable(int size, int probeType) {
    if (probeType >= 0 && probeType < NUM_PROBE_TYPES)
        this.probeType = probeType;
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid probeType: " + 
          probeType);

    table = new Entry[size];
    probeLengthCount = new int[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        probeLengthCount[i] = 0;
    }

    public HashTable(int size) {
    // Call the other constructor to do the work.
    this(size, LINEAR);
    }

    /* first hash function */
    private int h1(String key) {
    int h1 = key.hashCode() % table.length;
    if (h1 < 0)
        h1 += table.length;
    return h1;
    }

    /* second hash function */
    private int h2(String key) {
    int h2 = key.hashCode() % H2_DIVISOR;
    if (h2 < 0)
        h2 += H2_DIVISOR;
    h2 += H2_MIN;
    return h2;
    }

    /* 
     * probeIncrement - returns the amount by which the current index
     * should be incremented to obtain the nth element in the probe
     * sequence
     */
    private int probeIncrement(int n, int h2) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;

    switch (probeType) {
    case LINEAR:
        return 1;
    case QUADRATIC:
        return (2*n - 1);
    case DOUBLE_HASHING:
    default:
        return h2;
    }
    }

    /*
     * probe - attempt to find a slot in the hash table for the specified key.
     *
     * If key is currently in the table, it returns the index of the entry.
     * If key isn't in the table, it returns the index of the first empty cell
     * in the table.
     * If overflow occurs, it returns -1.
     */
    private int probe(String key) {
    int i = h1(key);    // first hash function
    int h2 = h2(key);   // second hash function
    int positionsChecked = 1;

    // keep probing until we get an empty position or a match
    while (table[i] != null && !key.equals(table[i].key)) {
        if (positionsChecked == table.length) {
        probeLengthCount[positionsChecked]++;
        return -1;
        }

        i = (i + probeIncrement(positionsChecked, h2)) % table.length;
        positionsChecked++;
    }

    probeLengthCount[positionsChecked]++; 
    return i;
    }

    /**
     * insert - insert the specified (key, value) pair in the hash table
     */
    public void insert(String key, int value) {
    if (key == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("key must be non-null");

    int i = h1(key); 
    int h2 = h2(key);
    int positionsChecked = 1;
    int firstRemoved = -1;

    while (table[i] != null && !key.equals(table[i].key)) {
        if (table[i].hasBeenRemoved && firstRemoved == -1)
        firstRemoved = i;

        if (positionsChecked == table.length)
        break;

        i = (i + probeIncrement(positionsChecked, h2)) % table.length;
        positionsChecked++;
    }

    probeLengthCount[positionsChecked]++; 

    if (table[i] != null && key.equals(table[i].key))
        table[i].valueList.addItem(value, 0);
    else if (firstRemoved != -1)
        table[firstRemoved] = new Entry(key, value);
    else if (table[i] == null)
        table[i] = new Entry(key, value);
    else
        throw new RuntimeException("overflow occurred");
    }

    /**
     * search - search for the specified key, and return the
     * associated list of values, or null if the key is not in the
     * table
     */
    public LLList search(String key) {
    if (key == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("key must be non-null");

    int i = probe(key);

    if (i == -1 || table[i] == null)
        return null;
    else
        return table[i].valueList;
    }

    /**
     * remove - remove from the table the entry for the specified key
     */
    public void remove(String key) {
    if (key == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("key must be non-null");

    int i = probe(key);
    if (i == -1 || table[i] == null)
        return;

    table[i].key = null;
    table[i].valueList = null;
    table[i].hasBeenRemoved = true;
    }

    /**
     * printStats - print the statistics for the table -- i.e., the
     * number of keys and items, and stats for the number of times
     * that probes of different lengths were performed
     */
    public void printStats() {
    int numProbes = 0;
    int probeLengthSum = 0;
    int numKeys = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        if (table[i] != null && !table[i].hasBeenRemoved)
        numKeys++;
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + numKeys + " keys");

    System.out.println("probe-length stats:");
    System.out.println("length\tcount");
    for (int i = 1; i <= table.length; i++) {
        if (probeLengthCount[i] != 0)
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + probeLengthCount[i]);
        numProbes += probeLengthCount[i];
        probeLengthSum += (probeLengthCount[i] * i);
    }
    System.out.println("average probe length = " +
      (double)probeLengthSum / numProbes);
    }
}
```

Here is the second file for a Linked-Linked-List

```
 /*
 * LLList.java
 *
 * 
 */

import java.util.*;

/**
 * A class that implements our simple List interface using a linked list.
 * The linked list includes a dummy head node that allows us to avoid
 * special cases for insertion and deletion at the front of the list.
 */
public class LLList implements List {
    // Inner class for a node.  We use an inner class so that the LLList
    // methods can access the instance variables of the nodes.
    private class Node {
    private Object item;
    private Node next;

    private Node(Object i, Node n) {
        item = i;
        next = n;
    }
    }

    private Node head;     // dummy head node
    private int length;    // # of items in the list

    /**
     * Constructs a LLList object for a list that is initially empty.
     */
    public LLList() {
    head = new Node(null, null);
    length = 0;
    }

    /* 
     * getNode - private helper method that returns a reference to the
     * ith node in the linked list.  It assumes that the value of the
     * parameter is valid.  
     * 
     * If i == -1, it returns a reference to the dummy head node.
     */
    private Node getNode(int i) {
    Node trav = head;
    int travIndex = -1;
    while (travIndex < i) {
        travIndex++;
        trav = trav.next;
    }
    return trav;
    }

    /** getItem - returns the item at position i in the list */
    public Object getItem(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= length)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    Node n = getNode(i);
    return n.item;
    }

    /** 
     * addItem - adds the specified item at position i in the list,
     * shifting the items that are currently in positions i, i+1, i+2,
     * etc. to the right by one.  Always returns true, because the list
     * is never full.
     *
     * We don't need a special case for insertion at the front of the
     * list (i == 0), because getNode(0 - 1) will return the dummy
     * head node, and the rest of insertion can proceed as usual.
     */
    public boolean addItem(Object item, int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > length)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    Node newNode = new Node(item, null);
    Node prevNode = getNode(i - 1);           
    newNode.next = prevNode.next;
    prevNode.next = newNode;

    length++;
    return true;
    }

    /** 
     * removeItem - removes the item at position i in the list,
     * shifting the items that are currently in positions i+1, i+2,
     * etc. to the left by one.  Returns a reference to the removed
     * object.
     *
     * Here again, we don't need a special case for i == 0 (see the
     * note accompanying addItem above).
     */
    public Object removeItem(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= length)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    Node prevNode = getNode(i - 1);           
    Object removed = prevNode.next.item;
    prevNode.next = prevNode.next.next;

    length--;
    return removed;
    }

    /** length - returns the number of items in the list */
    public int length() {
    return length;
    }

    /** 
     * isFull - always returns false, because the linked list can
     * grow indefinitely and thus the list is never full.
     */
    public boolean isFull() {
    return false;
    }

    /**
     * toString - converts the list into a String of the form 
     *      [ item0 item1 ... ]
     */
    public String toString() {
    String str = "[ ";

    Node trav = head.next;    // skip over the dummy head node
    while (trav != null) {
        str += (trav.item + " ");
        trav = trav.next;
    }

    str += "]";
    return str;
    }

    /**
     * iterator - returns an iterator for this list
     */
    public ListIterator iterator() {
    return new LLListIterator();
    }

    /*
     *** private inner class for an iterator over an LLList ***
     */
    private class LLListIterator implements ListIterator {
    private Node nextNode;          // the next node to visit    
    private Node lastVisitedNode;   // the most recently visited node

    public LLListIterator() {
        nextNode = head.next;
        lastVisitedNode = null;
    }

    /**
     * hasNext - does the iterator have additional items to visit?
     */
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (nextNode != null);
    }

    /**
     * next - returns a reference to the next Object in the iteration
     */
    public Object next() {
        if (nextNode == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

        Object item = nextNode.item;
        lastVisitedNode = nextNode;
        nextNode = nextNode.next;

        return item;
    }
    }
}
```