# Array w/ Generics

Tags: java, android, generics

I have read [What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java) .  I came to it when I tried this code:

```
HashMap<String, String>[] ret = new HashMap<String, String>[arraySize];
```

I decided to "get wild" and try something else

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ret = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Now, what I don't understand is why the first option is bad/not-supported and the second option compiles.

What am I missing?  In the first method I get an error and cannot compile while the second method has no compiler issues.

I prefer to follow intelligent programming principles, but do not understand the difference in this particular case.

Comment: An `ArrayList` is not an array. Or better yet, a random generic type is not an array (forget that it's called an `ArrayList`, it's just another type).

Comment: ty, but it does allow me to have an array of those objects, per se.  Maybe that is where I am confused?

Comment: You can look at the underlying implementation if you want. `ArrayList` uses a `Object[]`.

Comment: Oh, so what you're saying is that b/c an ArrayList instance is of a class, then it is able to bypass this requirement in that it can store an internal array of objects w/o having a requirement on the type of the object?

Comment: Can you re-attempt after removing the trailing parentheses in the line where you try to make an array of the HashMaps?

Comment: I don't understand the question in your comment. Regardless of what you put in the `ArrayList`, it will store it in an `Object[]` since `Object` is the parent type of all reference types. If you look at the implementation, you will notice that it satisfies the generic signature through casting.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you.  I will have to see how it works when I figure out how to find the source of `ArrayList`, but I believe you have answered the question (which guest has summarized).  If you post, I'll accept.  I guess the essence of the answer is that I am doing it correctly even if I don't fully understand why.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Your JDK installation contains a `src.zip` with all the source code. Alternatively, just search for `java ArrayList source code`. Grepcode.com should have what you need.

Comment: Thanks... I haven't looked for that source before, just Android source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point out what you already know, the second one compiles. An ArrayList is not an array, so *your program* obviously won't run into the generic array problem.

You're probably wondering how `ArrayList` does it then. In the implementation of `ArrayList` that I've seen, it internally uses an `Object` array--not generic. The class just does a lot of casting.