# Creating an Array Heap in Java

Tags: java, arrays, binary-heap

So i am trying to make an array based generic heap that i can use with my tester class. Much of what i have is based of my understandings of trees and some research online as well as from my textbook; both which have very limited info on what i am looking for. However, i did manage to get all the methods in need and when i run it, i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
    at q1.Heaps.<init>(Heaps.java:23)
    at q1.createGui.<init>(Gui.java:46)
    at q1.Gui.main(Gui.java:18)
```

Im guessing it has to do with how i declare and initialize my Comparable array, which i am having trouble figuring out how to.

```
package q1;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class Heaps<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    Comparable[] data;
    int size;

    /**
     * Constructor with s as size
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Heaps(int s) {
        size = 0;
        data = (E[]) new Object[s];
    }

    /**
     * Adds a value to the heap
     */
    public void add(E value) {
        if (full()) // expand array
            ensureCapacity(2*size);
        size++;
        data[size] = value;
        if (size > 1)
            heapifyUp();
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the array is full
     */
    private boolean full()
    { 
        return (size == data.length-1);
    }

    private void heapifyUp()
    {
        Comparable<E> temp;
        int next = size;
        while (next != 1 && data[next].compareTo(data[next/2]) > 0)
        {
            temp = data[next];
            data[next] = data[next/2];
            data[next/2] = temp;
            next = next/2;
        }
    }

    private void heapifyDown()
    {
        Comparable<E> temp;
        int next = 0;
        while (next*2 <= size) // node has a child
        {
            int child = 2*next; // left child
            if (child < size &&
                    data[child].compareTo(data[child+1]) > 0)//left smaller than right
                child++; // right child instead
            if (data[next].compareTo(data[child]) > 0)
            {
                temp = data[next];
                data[next] = data[child];
                data[child] = temp;
                next = child;
            }
            else;
            next = size; // stop loop
        }//end while
    }

    /**
     * Removes all occurrence of element
     */
    public boolean removeAll(E element) {
        if (contains(element) && !(isEmpty())){
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                if(element.equals(data[i])){
                    data[i] = data[size-1];
                }
                heapifyDown();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Removes 1st occurrence of element
     */
    public boolean remove(E element) {
        if (contains(element) && !(isEmpty())){
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                if(element.equals(data[i])){
                    data[i] = data[size-1];
                    heapifyDown();
                    return true;
                }   
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public Comparable<E>[] ensureCapacity(int s) {
        return Arrays.copyOf(data, 2*s);
    }

    /**
     * Converts the heap into its String representation.
     *   @return the String representation
     */

    public Comparable<E>[] iteratorPreOrder() 
    {
        Comparable<E>[] temp = (E[]) new Object[size];
        temp[0] = data[0];
        int i = 1;
        int count = 1;
        while(data[2*i] != null){
            temp[count] = data[2*i];
            ++i;
            ++count;
        }
        i = 1;
        while(data[(2*i) +1] != null){
            temp[count] = data[(2*i) +1];
            ++i;
            ++count;
        }
        return temp;
    }


    public int countOccurance(E element){
        int count = 0;
        for (int i =0; i < size; i++){
            if(element.equals(data[i])){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public boolean contains (E element) 
    {
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
            if (element.equals(data[i])){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you could please show me how i would solve this problem, i would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

EDIT: SO i edited the my class and now it works when i do `data = (E[]) new Comparable[s]`. So why does java not allow generic Array types, what makes it different from Arraylist, Stacks, Queues, and/or LinkedList which can be generic?

Comment: You've nailed the root of the issue on the head: `data = (E[]) new Object[s]` in your constructor is indeed the problem

Comment: @Chris ya, but now i just need a solution :(

Comment: For your edit, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2927427/836214) - _Arrays of generic types are not allowed because they're not sound. The problem is due to the interaction of Java arrays, which are not statically sound but are dynamically checked, with generics, which are statically sound and not dynamically checked_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an Object[] and then trying to cast it to a Comprable[]. The compiler was telling you what you did wrong with the unchecked cast error.

You want data to be `E[] data` and the line to be:

```
data = new E[s];
```

Note: this could run into issues with how Java handles generics.

Comment: I am not sure that it will be able to create an array of type E[] due to type erasure. Do not have an IDE on hand to check.

Comment: The compiler wouldnt let me use data = new E[s] as i get the error: cannot create generic array of E.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid something like this would happen. Try one of the ideas from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: @KonstantinNaryshkin interesting, but i got it to work, check my edited post.

Comment: @KonstantinNaryshkin - please edit your answer to be more correct - as is, it might attract negative attention due to the incorrect code.