# instantiating java array using generics

Tags: java, generics

I am creating a list data structure and am having trouble with the generics syntax for actually using it. All I am trying to do is create an instance of `ArrayLinearList<String>` and of size 2 and put some strings in it. I have been trying to figure out why setting the first slot to "one" is not correct. This is the error and my code snippet.

```
   myList[0] = "one";
```

The error message is: **error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to `ArrayLinearList<String>`**

```
public class ArrayLinearList<E> implements LinearListADT<E> {


 private Object[] array;
int currentSize = 0;

//Constructor (no arguments)
public ArrayLinearList() {
    currentSize = 2;  
    // array = (ArrayLinearList[]) new Object[2];   //Start with a container of size 2
    array = new Object[2];
}
   public static void main(String[] var0) {

       ArrayLinearList<String>[] myList;
       myList = new ArrayLinearList[2];
       myList[0] = "one";
   }
}
```

I am having quite a bit of trouble with the syntax with using generics in java. In my mind I have an array of size 2 where I am going to be placing strings. I will add more methods later but I want to understand why my current syntax is incorrect for placing this string in the array.

Comment: Generally speaking, generics and arrays don't mix in Java.  Use a List instead.

Comment: @guillermoalvarez, I suggest you take a quick read through this clearly written tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html

Comment: @tgm1024: I'd describe compiler errors on "new T[]" and "new Foo<Bar>[]" as "not mixing."  I fully understand the difference between invariant generics and covariant arrays, but trying to squeeze generics and arrays together is rarely a good idea in practice, and using a `List` is almost always a better alternative that doesn't force you to suppress compiler warnings or perform unsafe casts.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I'm not saying you're declaring that as mixed.  But curious: Where do you perceive the unsafe cast in using arrays?  A String array is of a type.  ``ArrayList<String>`` is of a type.  Do you have an example of the unsafe cast you mention?  As I see it, the only confusion left is in covariance.

Comment: Usually you have to do `(Foo<Bar>[]) new Foo[n]` to get an array of a generic type, and that'll give you an unchecked cast warning.  And that _can_ lead to ClassCastExceptions at runtime, precisely because arrays are covariant and generics are invariant.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, Ah, Gotcha, my apologies. I misunderstood where you were going.  For anyone else curious about this, see the explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2927427/4229245, and here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
   ArrayLinearList<String>[] myList;
```

you define an array that holds `ArrayLinearList<String>` elements, not Strings, this is why you get the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your code here

```
ArrayLinearList<String>[] myList;
myList = new ArrayLinearList[2];//you have defining array myList of type ArrayLinearList
myList[0] = "one";//you are trying to store String to array which can hold ArrayLinearList
```

Here `ArrayLinearList<String>` means that your list will hold values of type String (provided we define it correctly in the code). But `ArrayLinearList<String>[]` will hold only reference of type ArrayLinearList and not String itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
myList.array[0] = "one";
```

Because `myList` is not an array. It's an object which you use to store an array within.