# Default constructor issue when creating an array Java

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have the following class:

```
public class ArrayObjects<E> implements SomeImp<E>{
    int maxCapacity, actualSize;

    public ArrayObjects(){
        maxCapacity = 10;
        array = (E[]) new Object[maxCapacity];
    }
}
```

Eclipse marks an error and says the following:

"array cannot be resolved to a variable"

Also it shows some additional details:

-Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object[] to E[]

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? My goal is to have an array in my class constructor that can hold any kind of object (that's why I am trying to make it generic) but apparently this approach will not work.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: [Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. There is no declared variable by the name of `array`.

```
public class ArrayObjects<E> implements SomeImp<E> {
    int maxCapacity, actualSize;
    E[] array; // <- The missing declaration

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // <- Suppress the "unchecked cast" warning
    public ArrayObjects() {
        maxCapacity = 10;
        array = (E[]) new Object[maxCapacity];
    }
}
```

As far as the unchecked cast goes, the best thing you can do there is to suppress it as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Another kind of beginner question. What's the difference if I put public in front of my int/ E[ ]  declarations? Thanks again

Comment: @JTarantino public means the variable is visible from other classes

Comment: Here is a good resource that describes access modifiers in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html