# Adding ".foreach" capability to a custom container class

Tags: java, java-8

I wrote my own container class for my game, similar to that of an ArrayList however different in quite a few ways, anyhow I want to write a foreach method that will iterate over the backing array.

I know that I could just use `Arrays.stream` however I'm curious as to how it would look to write a custom lambda implementation of the #foreach method for iteration over an array.

Anybody have a clue? Thanks

Example:

```
class Container<T> {
    T[] array = new T[200]; 
}
```

Now for instance lets say I wanted to do this:

```
Container<Fish> fishies = new Container();
fishies.forEach(fish->System::out);
```

Comment: You can't new `Generic`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.forEach%28java.util.function.Consumer%29

Comment: @Chengphoi (T[]) new Obejct[200];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a `forEach` method similar to that of the `Stream` interface in your `Container` class :

```
void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        action.accept(array[i]);
}
```

This `forEach` implementation is serial, so it's much simpler than the `Stream` implementations, which can also be parallel.

I'm ignoring the fact that `T[] array = new T[200];` doesn't pass compilation, as that's a different issue.

Comment: `T[] array = (T[]) new Object[200];` Sorry.

Comment: Of course, `for(T t: array) action.accept(t);` will do as well…

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to create a method which returns the stream:

```
Stream<T> stream() {
    return Arrays.stream(array);
    // or probably Arrays.stream(array, 0, size); if it's used partially
}
```

This way the users will have not only `forEach`, but every operation supported by streams.

Comment: Yes! Returning a stream is far more useful than exposing a mere forEach.

Comment: However, not what the question asked.