# Generic Comparator warnings

Tags: java, generics

I have this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class MyComparator<K,V> implements Comparator<Map.Entry<K,List<V>>> {

    public int compare(Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me1, Map.Entry<K,List<V>> me2) {

                List<V> v1 = me1.getValue();
                List<V> v2 = me2.getValue(); 

                if(v1.size() > v2.size())
                    return 1;
                else if(v1.size() < v2.size())
                    return -1;
                else
                     return 0;
    }
}

public class Anagrams1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int minGroupSize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        // Read words from file and put into a simulated multimap
        Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                String word = s.next();
                String alpha = alphabetize(word);
                List<String> l = m.get(alpha);
                if (l == null)
                    m.put(alpha, l=new ArrayList<String>());
                l.add(word);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Print all permutation groups above size threshold
        Collection<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>> c = m.entrySet();
        Object[] arr = c.toArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr, new MyComparator());
        for(Object o : arr) {
            if(m.get(o).size() >= minGroupSize)

                System.out.println(o + " : " + m.get(o).size() + ": " + m.get(o)); 

        }
    }

    private static String alphabetize(String s) {
        char[] a = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(a);
        return new String(a);
    }
}
```

This is giving me two warnings:

```
  javacode$ javac -Xlint:unchecked Anagrams1.java

  Anagrams1.java:45: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method sort in class Arrays is applied to given types
          Arrays.sort(arr, new MyComparator());

                     ^
    required: T[],Comparator<? super T>

    found: Object[],MyComparator

    where T is a type-variable:

      T extends Object declared in method <T>sort(T[],Comparator<? super T>)

  Anagrams1.java:45: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion

          Arrays.sort(arr, new MyComparator());

                           ^
    required: Comparator<? super T>

    found:    MyComparator

    where T is a type-variable:

      T extends Object declared in method <T>sort(T[],Comparator<? super T>)
```

Help needed. Thanks.

Comment: Well, since this is the third question (including the deleted one) about generics and (almost) the same code: have you ever read something about generics? How they work and how one can use them?

Comment: @Tom I read the tutorial and I am reading it again. I felt getting tips from people to supplement with my reading would be a good and quick way to learn. I am currently reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to this that I'd suggest:

1. Use [Collection#toArray(T[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T[])) to get an array of the elements of type `T[]`. This is tricky and icky because you'd need `T` to be `Map.Entry<K,List<V>>`, and you can't create one of those directly since generics are non-reifiable types.
2. Copy the elements into an `ArrayList` (e.g. using `new ArrayList<>(m.entrySet())`) and then call `Collections.sort` on that.

The latter would be my preferred approach, since Collections have type safety advantages over plain arrays.

Comment: "and you can't create one of those directly since generics are non-reifiable types." What does that mean ? Can you please explain in simplistic terms ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `class MyComparator<K,V>`.

You're calling `new MyComparator()`. With an `Object[]`.

This should give you the exact warning it's giving you - it's expecting to be defined `new MyComparator<String, String>()` based on your code.

I'd also recommend passing in a properly typed `List` instead of an `Object[]` as the first argument, and using `Collections.sort` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This would still give you a warning in the assignment of the `Map.Entry[]` to `Map.Entry<String,List<String>>[]`, but the `Arrays.sort` call won't give any warning :

```
    Map.Entry<String,List<String>>[] arr = c.toArray(new Map.Entry[0]);
    Arrays.sort(arr, new MyComparator<String,String>());
```

I don't think you can get away with that warning if you want to use an array for the sorting, since you can't create an instance of a generic array, so `c.toArray(new Map.Entry<String,List<String>>[0])` won't pass compilation.

Comment: Using `Collections.sort` will eliminate the need to use an array (and that extra warning)

Comment: I could not compile after the changes: javacode$ java Anagrams1 ./dictionary.txt 8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.Map$Entry;
 at Anagrams1.main(Anagrams1.java:44)

Trying Collections.sort approach now.

Comment: Why could not I do the cast, why the error as above ?

Comment: @abc Try the new code. I tried multiple versions of this code and ended up posing a version I didn't check that didn't work. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Eran It worked, but gave two warnings 
code : http://pastebin.com/zE3vM5uk
Warnings: http://pastebin.com/9f9FqxRv