# How can I create an array of items whose entries have generic fields?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, nested-generics

I have this code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>(1000);
    }
}

class Foo<Key extends Comparable<Key>>{
    private Entry[] a;
    private class Entry{
        Key key;
    }
    public Foo(int size){
        a = (Entry[])new Object[size]; // <- this is the problem
    }
}
```

when I compile it, I get an error, saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LFoo$Entry;
at Foo.<init>(Main.java:17)
at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

I tried:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>(1000);
    }
}

class Foo<Key extends Comparable<Key>>{
    private Entry[] a;
    private class Entry{
        Key key;
    }
    public Foo(int size){
        a = new Entry[size];
    }
}
```

But then I got an error saying:

```
Main.java:17: error: generic array creation
        a = new Entry[size];
            ^
```

Is it possible to create that array at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually you can via `reflection`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>(1000);
        foo.a[0] = foo.new Entry();
        foo.a[0].key = "ss";
    }
}

class Foo<Key extends Comparable<Key>> {
    public Entry[] a;

    public class Entry {
        Key key;
    }

    public Foo(int size) {
        a = (Entry[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Entry.class, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't java do this by default? Sounds like a pain to have to cast and write this long winded method call.

Comment: you can always do `import java.lang.reflect;` and write simple `...Array.newInstance(...`

Answer (score 1):

It because [Generics don't cope very well with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2931240/1003142) (at compile-time).

You should rather use some Collection, instead:

```
class Foo<Key extends Comparable<Key>> {
    private List<Entry> a;

    private class Entry {
        Key key;
    }

    public Foo(int size) {
        a = new ArrayList<Entry>(size);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance` ?

Comment: Yes, the approach with Reflection is nice, but I'd rather use a Collection, instead of doing such workarounds. :)

Comment: May be he *must* use arrays, we don't know

Answer (score 1):

I agree with kocko that you should use some `Collection` instead of arrays.  But specifically to your point, this compiles and runs for me.  This just pushes off the responsibility for creating the array to the `Array.newInstance` method.  The downside is it forces the cast

```
 class Foo<Key extends Comparable<Key>>{
     private Entry[] a;
     private class Entry{
       Key key;
     }
     public Foo(int size){
       a = (Entry[])Array.newInstance(Entry.class,size);
     }
}
```

Comment: @Andremoniy Story of my life. :P

Answer (score 0):

Being an inner class, the `Entry` type is within the scope of the type parameter `Key` declared in the enclosing class. In other words, `Entry` is also generic.

You can use

```
a = (Entry[]) new Foo<?>.Entry[size];
```

or the raw equivalent (which I don't recommend)

```
a = (Entry[]) new Foo.Entry[size];
```

This type of [array creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) is explained in the JLS

> ```
> ArrayCreationExpression:
>     new ClassOrInterfaceType DimExprs [Dims]
> ```

stating

> It is a compile-time error if the `ClassOrInterfaceType` **does not denote
>   a reifiable type** ([§4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7)).

where a [*reifiable type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7) is

> A type is reifiable if and only if one of the following holds:
>
> - **It refers to a non-generic class or interface type declaration.**
> - **It is a parameterized type in which all type arguments are unbounded wildcards (§4.5.1).**
> - **It is a raw type (§4.8).**
> - It is a primitive type (§4.2).
> - It is an array type (§10.1) whose element type is reifiable.
> - **It is a nested type where, for each type `T` separated by a ".", `T` itself is reifiable.**

By using the parameterization with a wildcard or the raw type, we can get the array creation expression presented above.