# How to "check" a cast?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, android-studio, casting

I wrote a method that gets a random value from a `Map`. I first got all the values in the map and use a `Random` object to get a random one. Here is the method:

```
public static <K, V> V getRandomValInMap (Map<K, V> map) {
    Collection<V> values = map.values ();
    V[] array = (V[])values.toArray ();
    return array[random.nextInt (array.length)];
}
```

In the expression

```
(V[])values.toArray ()
```

Android Studio said that it is an "unchecked cast from `Object[]` to `V[]`". So I guess this is kind of "risky". I tried using another overload of `toArray`:

```
V[] array = new V[values.size()];
array = values.toArray (array);
```

And I guess this is not how you would use the overload because there's a compiler error saying that I cannot initialize `V`.

So I think maybe I should use the first method. But how do I "check" a cast to cancel the warning?

Or, you can tell me how to use the `toArray(T[] array)` overload correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better aproach would be not to create new array at all:

```
public static <K, V> V getRandomValInMap (Map<K, V> map) {
    Collection<V> values = map.values ();

    Iterator<V> it = values.iterator();
    int choosen = new Random().nextInt (values.size());
    for (int i=0; i<values.size();i++) {
        V value = it.next();
        if (i==choosen) return value;
    }
    throw new AssertionError("Choosen value out of bounds");
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I like your idea. Let me try that.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create an array of a generic type, this is a known limitation in Java and there are good reasons about it. So this is not possible: `V[] array = new V[values.size()];`

See also:

[What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could check it in runtime, using `instanceof`, but if you know, that only correct type of objects will be in the map, you should just leave it as it is - fixing a warning with unnecessary runtime overhead is a bad idea. This warning basically means, that there is no way to be sure that you always get correct objects from the map.

The `new V` does not work because of *type erasure*. This was a design decision in Java to keep backwards compatibility, when generics was introduced.

If you only care about the warning, you can suppress it of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in Java, The generics type will be removed when compile and deal it as `Object` type.

You can suppress warning by:

```
public static <K, V> V getRandomValInMap (Map<K, V> map) {
    Collection<V> values = map.values ();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") V[] array = (V[])values.toArray ();
    return array[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Bruce Eckel in Thinking in Java *using **Array.newInstance** is the recommended approach to create arrays in generics*.

```
public class ArrayMaker<T> { 
 private Class<T> kind; 
 public ArrayMaker(Class<T> kind) { this.kind = kind; } 
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
 T[] create(int size) { 
  return (T[])Array.newInstance(kind, size); 
 }
}
```

You can use this approach and populate your array from keys and values of your Map.