# How to avoid @SuppressWarnings on generic arrays

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code

```
ParameterExpression<String>[] searchStrings = new ParameterExpression[10];
```

Which works but will give a warning stating that I am doing an `"unchecked"` operation which is the case.

I want to get rid of the warning without doing a `@SupressWarnings` but if I do

```
ParameterExpression<String>[] searchStrings = new ParameterExpression<String>[10];
```

I get an error

> Cannot create a generic array of ParameterExpression

Is there anyway to remove the warning without using `@SupressWarnings`?

Comment: Is there any class that is a concrete implementation of ParametersExpression that you will use?

Comment: You might check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java

Comment: Not without making it specific to the JPA provider http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/ParameterExpression.html

Comment: Just use a `List`.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano it seems your best is a `List` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With arrays, you cannot initialize using generic classes, but you can do a list

```
List<ParameterExpression<String>> searchStrings = new ArrayList<>();
```