# Why couldn't arrays of generics be implemented in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

#### Java uses type erasure

It is my understanding that `new ArrayList<String>()` is converted into its raw type, and that a lot of syntactic sugar is used to pretend that this ArrayList of Object acts like an ArrayList of String. Java refers to this as type erasure.

#### For example

This is what I wrote in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.add("foo");
    String s = stringList.get(0);
}
```

When I decompiled the byte code, I got this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList();
    stringList.add("foo");
    String s = (String)stringList.get(0);
}
```

#### Therefore

Why couldn't `new T[]` be converted to `(T[]) new Object[]` **automatically**, using the same *"shtick"* the compiler pulls for type erasure?

Please don't refer me to this question: [What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2927391/7711481) In particular this comment:

> The problem is deeper than pointed in that answer, so further
>   investigation is needed. As you said type info is erased and in
>   compiled code we have no difference between two generic types - all we
>   have is base type - so why for `T[]` - compile to `Object[]`. In this case
>   everything will be fine - array will remember that it was created with
>   object type and will let save all types. However as for me the real
>   problem is that arrays are covariant meaning that `Animal[]` can be
>   assigned to `Object[]`. On the other hand generics are not `ArrayList<Animal>`
>   can not be assigned to `ArrayList<Object>`

Because this logic is flawed!

There are two processes going on here.

1. The compiler enforces an *"artificial"* invariance to `ArrayList<String>`.
2. The compiler casts the `Object` into `T`.

Again, why couldn't arrays of generics be implemented in Java using the simple syntactic sugar that form all generics, while maintaining the normal covariance of arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code throws an exception:

```
static <T> T[] newArray() {
    return (T[]) new Object[0];
}
static {
    // throws ClassCastException,
    // because Object[] is not a String[].
    String[] a = newArray();
}
```

This happens because `String[]` and `Object[]` actually have different types at run-time. (This is unlike generics: for example, `List<String>` and `List<Object>` have the same class.)

With your suggestion, the method `newArray` would just look like this:

```
static <T> T[] newArray() {
    return new T[0];
}
```

That's not obviously wrong, but it is. I think this change would just cause more confusion for few actual gains.

Conceivably, they could have completely changed the way that arrays work, so that they only have compile-time subtyping and are all just `Object[]` at run-time. This would have been a pretty major change, though, and would break old code.

Personally, I think they should just add a generic `class Array<E>` which would serve the same purpose as a generic array. It's pretty rare to actually need one in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

Type safety can be enforced in two ways: at runtime or compile time.

Arrays enforce it at runtime:

```
Object[] array = new Integer[1];
array[0] = "";
// ArrayStoreException!
```

Generics enforce it at compile time:

```
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// does not compile!

List<? extends Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(1);
// does not compile!
```

Because `T[]` is an array, it must be covariant, but because of type erasure, there's no way to check the type at runtime, as demonstrated in this example:

```
Object[] array = (T[])new Object[1];
array[0] = 1;
```

Since at runtime `array` actually *is* of type `Object[]`, this code will compile and run without error, regardless of what `T` happens to be. That causes [heap pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_pollution), which often results in your code failing at some unpredictable place or time, making it difficult to diagnose and fix. Hence the warning.