# Java connecting 2 hash maps including duplicate keys

Tags: java

i'm trying to find a way to take 2 txt files, read them into my java class (put them in hash map) and then connect them into one hash map (which i will write latter into a txt file)
something like this:
i want txt3 to have all the words from txt1 and txt2

**txt1**

```
word1 -> [a] [b] [c]
word2 -> [r]
```

**txt2**

```
word1 -> [z] [d] 
word3 -> [k]
```

**txt3 - what i want to create**

```
word1 -> [a] [b] [c] [z] [d]
word2 -> [r]
word3 -> [k]
```

in my code

wordline[0] = word1

wordline[1] = ->

wordline[2] = [a][b][c]

code

```
public void readPartialPosting() {
    HashMap<String, String>[] dictionary1 = new HashMap[2];
    dictionary1[0]=new HashMap<>();
    dictionary1[1]=new HashMap<>();
    File fromFile;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        fromFile = new File("1.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fromFile));
        String st;
        String[] wordLine;
        String term;
        String termLocation;
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            wordLine = st.split(" ", 3);
            term = wordLine[0];
            termLocation = wordLine[2];
            dictionary1[0].put(term, termLocation);
        }
        fromFile = new File("2.txt");
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fromFile));
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            wordLine = st.split(" ", 3);
            term = wordLine[0];
            termLocation = wordLine[2];
            dictionary1[1].put(term, termLocation);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

so at the end of code basically i have the txt1 and txt2 from above and now im trying to create txt3 somehow, but i'm not sure how to connect the list in case i have duplicate key (and then i just want to add the strings together one after each other and not overwrite)

i'm not even sure if my idea for hash map is the right solution here maybe a different structure?

i saw compute function while reading on the forum but i'm not sure if that can help me and not sure how to use exactly.

hope i post in forum like asked in tips.
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8 features the two `Map` objects in `dictionary1` can be combined as follows.

Note: Changed `dictionary1` from array to `List` to eliminate compiler warnings/errors about generic arrays. You shouldn't use generic arrays if you can avoid it.

*Solution (Java 8+)*

```
Map<String, String> merged = new TreeMap<>();
dictionary1.forEach(d -> 
    d.forEach((k, v) ->
        merged.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> v1 + " " + v2)
    )
);
```

Changed `HashMap` to `TreeMap` so result is in alphabetical order.

*Test (Java 9+)*

```
List<Map<String, String>> dictionary1 = List.of(
        Map.of("word1", "[a] [b] [c]",
               "word2", "[r]"),
        Map.of("word1", "[z] [d]",
               "word3", "[k]")
);
// code from above here
merged.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
word1=[a] [b] [c] [z] [d]
word2=[r]
word3=[k]
```

Comment: you can simplify it further as Maps have a `forEach` i.e. `dictionary1.forEach(d -> d.forEach((key, value) -> merged.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> v1 + " " + v2)));`

Comment: @Aomine Thanks. Forgot about that one. Answer updated. :-)

Comment: thanks for answer, i have a problem tho i'm new to lambda expression. first i get an error at "List.of( Map.of("word1", "[a] [b] [c]", "word2", "[r]"), Map.of("word1", "[z] [d]", "word3", "[k]")" with the words "of" it says "cannot resolve method of" btw, im using jdk 8 beacuse of javafx support that is lost in future sdk's------------- second question "You shouldn't use generic arrays if you can avoid it." what is the problem with generic arrays? since my code does work if i do " List<Map<String, String>> dictionary1 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(); " –

Comment: @ItzikDan #1 The test code is Java 9, but the solution is Java 8. --- #2 See [What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2927391/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to encapsulate creating dictionary from the file into separate method:

```
public static Map<String, String> createFileDictionary(String path) throws IOException {
    File fromFile = new File(path);

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fromFile))) {
        Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
        String str;

        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = str.split(" ", 3);
            dictionary.put(parts[0], parts[2]);
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Then using you can ready your files and put all dictionaries' items into single map.

```
// java 8 or higher
private static void putAll(Map<String, String> dest, Map<String, String> src) {
    src.forEach((key, val) -> dest.merge(key, val, (s1, s2) -> s1 + ' ' + s2));
}

// java 7 or earlier
private static void putAll(Map<String, String> dest, Map<String, String> src) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : src.entrySet()) {
        if (dest.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
            dest.put(entry.getKey(), dest.get(entry.getKey()) + ' ' + entry.getValue());
        else
            dest.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

And use it in your client's code:

```
Map<String, String> fileDictionary = new HashMap<>();
putAll(fileDictionary, createFileDictionary("1.txt"));
putAll(fileDictionary, createFileDictionary("2.txt"));
```