# Eclipse - why infer generic suggested for Java's array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, generics

[You cannot create arrays of parameterized types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java), so this code in Eclipse

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] list = new ArrayList[1];
```

Can't be parameterized , but Eclipse shows a warning

> Type safety: The expression of type `ArrayList[]` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `ArrayList<Integer>[]`

And also shows suggestion [Infer Generic Type Arguments](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-refactor.htm) which does nothing when submitted.

> *Infer Generic Type Arguments* Replaces raw type occurrences of generic types by parameterized types after identifying all places where this replacement is possible.

Should this suggestion be removed or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the suggestion should be removed. It is not possible to replace the raw type with a parameterized type here, because an array creation expression must use a reifiable type as the component type. It's illegal to do `new ArrayList<Integer>[1]`. You can only do `new ArrayList[1]` or `new ArrayList<?>[1]`, both of which will produce a warning in order to convert to type `ArrayList<Integer>[]` (the second one will require an explicit cast which produces an unchecked cast warning).