# How would you refactor Arrays.copyOf() method in order to remove the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I was looking inside Arrays class in java and saw that @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation is being used in the following code.

```
    public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
        ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
        : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

How would you refactor the following code in order to remove @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation?

Comment: You can't, [because you can't create array of generic type in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java). So you would have to typecast.

Comment: @AdwaitKumar But we do know the runtime type of `T[]` here. The problem is that there isn't an `Array.newInstance` with an appropriate signature.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline The problem is not the *signature* of `Array.newInstance(Class<?>, int)`, but its *return type*. It’s declared to return `Object` to cater for the case where the element type is a primitive type so the array type is not a subtype of `Object[]`.

Comment: Yeah, signature is the wrong term. I mean to include the return type, the type of `componentType` and that it is the `length` version not `dimensions` (which has *another* reason not to return `T[]`). Perhaps *signatures* is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here.

```
public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
T[] copy = newType.cast(
    Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength)
);
```

But it is not as fast, which is important for this method.

Comment: why it is not so fast?

Comment: @IonKat There's a call to `Class.cast` and no special case for `Object[]`.

Comment: Sorry, but with my current knowledge level I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: but then the source of `Class.cast()` itself has a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, so in some sense this just moves the annotation from one place to another

Comment: @newacct That would be an implementation detail. The important thing is that it's a sound library method.