# unable to use constructor in java

Tags: java, generics

I have started learing java generics and this is my priority queue implementation:

```
public class MinPQ<Key> implements Iterable<Key> {
   private Key[] pq;                    // store items at indices 1 to n
   private int n;                       // number of items on priority queue
   private Comparator<Key> comparator;  // optional comparator

   public MinPQ(Key[] keys) {
        n = keys.length;
        pq = (Key[]) new Object[keys.length + 1];
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

And this is my main class :

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int[] ar = {1,2,3};
            MinPQ<Integer> pq = new MinPQ<Integer>(ar);
        }
}
```

But here I get an error stating **"The constructor MinPQ(int[]) is undefined"** can someone please help me find the issue here ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java)

Comment: Don't create arrays of generic type as you have problems with type erasure. Instead use a `List<Key>` or other generic collection.

Comment: As @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter said, you will probably have an easier time with `List<Key>`. However, as an exercise try changing `ar` to `Integer[]` rather than `int[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use primitive types with generics. Just change:

```
int[] ar = {1,2,3};
```

to:

```
Integer[] ar = {1,2,3};
```

or box it with

```
IntStream.of(ar).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new)
```

Basically you're trying to pass an `int[]` to a constructor which requires `Integer[]`, because of `MinPQ<Integer>` declaration. So, in tehory it should work if you declared it as `MinPQ<int>` - but as stated at the beginning we can't use primitive types for generics.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can use `IntStream.of(intArray).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new)` to convert a pre-existing `int[]` to an `Integer[]`

Comment: @pafauk. It seems to work, Ur a lifesaver...

Comment: Cool, I'll add it to the answer - the array might be not under your control

Comment: yup after specifying <Integer> parameter type in initialization it worked...