# Why IDEA shows that “Type parameter 'T' cannot be instantiated directly”. What I want to do is declare a generic array

Tags: java, intellij-idea, data-structures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTwNg.png)

the code is below:

```
package linear_list;

public class SeqList<T> {
    protected int n;        
    protected T[] element;
    private static final int MIN_CAPACITY=16;
    public SeqList(int length){
        if (length<MIN_CAPACITY)
            length=MIN_CAPACITY;
        this.element=new T[length];   //this row is reported an error
        this.n=0;
    }
}
```

Why IDEA shows that “Type parameter 'T' cannot be instantiated directly”. What I want to do is declare a generic array.

Comment: Generic are for compile time type safety, so if you initialize generic variable it should know the type of object at compile time. So generic type object can not be initialized this way. Rather you would need to take this as input from user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java)

Comment: You can do something like this `T newT = (T[]) element.getClass().newInstance()`

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa you can't do that until `element` is initialized.

Comment: @maloomeister Yes

Comment: Just cast an object array. `(T[]) new Object[10];`