# Generic Array initialisation

Tags: java, arrays, generics, erasure

I have read through different articles which talks about why we cannot create generic array in java, but still I don't quite understand why.

For example, it this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generic-array), it assumed if generic array initialisation is possible, there will be casting issue after erasure. You can find the details in section [2. Considerations When Using Generic Arrays](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generic-array#considerations-when-using-generic-arrays). In simplest term, the generic array becomes an Object Array after erasure, and if the generic type is String, java will fail to cast Object[] to String[].

However, I created a generic class with a simple function,

```
// Test.java
public class Test<T> {
    public T[] getStrArr(T[] arr) {
        return arr;
    }
}

//Main.java
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test<String> test = new Test<>();
        String[] strArr = test.getStrArr(new String[]{"A", "B", "C"});
}
```

After erasure, the getStringArr should return Object[], and it is able to cast to String[] without any problem.

Another  stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java) stated that:

**arrays (unlike generics) contain, at runtime, information about its component type. So you must know the component type when you create the array. Since you don't know what T is at runtime, you can't create the array.**

but erasure will change `T` into `Object` type, so compiler can create array with Object type.

There are other posts with similar explanation but cannot really resolve my doubt.

Please help!

Comment: *After erasure, the getStringArr should return Object[]* -> no it doesn't, because it does **not** create a generic array. You're the one passing in a `String[]` so the `getStrArr` doesn't have to do any array creation at all

Comment: @Lino, thanks for the reply. the return type of getStringArr is T[], according to erasure => Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. so the return type should becomes Object[]. I am referencing https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: When using generics the compiler "cheats" by adding implicit casting. Because you pass a `String[]` into the method, and then return it directly, the final cast (to `String[]`) when assigning the return value of `getStrArr()` to `strArr` will work, because the returned value **is** a `String[]`

Comment: @Lino, you are right, I missed the very basic thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After erasure, the getStringArr should return Object[], and it is able
> to cast to String[] without any problem.

Return type of the `getStrArr`, after type erasure, would be `Object[]` but, in your code, it is returning `arr` which is of type `String[]`. That is why there is not `ClassCastException` in your code.

Consider the following method (suppose generic arrays were allowed):

```
public T[] foo() {
    return new T[5];                  
}
```

After type erasure, `new T[5]` will be replaced by `new Object[5]`. Now if the calling code calls this method as:

```
String[] strArr = obj.foo();
```

It will lead to `ClassCastException` because `Object[]` cannot be casted to `String[]`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response. Clear explanation on the first part, understood now, thanks a lot. For the second part, I know it is a problem to create array with generic class, just as you explained. But it is not quite related to using generic parameter to create array, which is new T[].  So after your explanation, my understanding is we cannot use new T[] because it is not possible to do the casting. Hope I got it right.

Comment: I have removed the second part related to parameterized arrays. Generic arrays cause problems related to casting and that is why they are not allowed.