# Generic function to swap rows and columns in an array

Tags: java

I want to make a function which can take any type of array (`int`, `String`, `boolean`, etc) and return an array of the same type with the rows and columns switched.

```
public static String[][] swap_rows_columns_str_arr(String[][] arr) {
    String[][] new_arr = new String[arr[0].length][arr.length];
    for (int col = 0; col < arr[0].length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
            new_arr[col][row] = arr[row][col];
        }
    }
    return new_arr;
}
```

I've managed to get it work for singular datatypes, but how would I get it to work for any datatype?

Comment: Welcome to the rabbit hole of type erasure. Unfortunately, to my knowledge, you'll have to dip into a bit of reflection to allocate an array of generic type. It's far more complicated than it has any right to be.

Comment: Better to work with nested Lists of generic type, `List<List<T>>` than with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic type `<T>`, but you have to use [`Array.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int...)) to create the array (see [What's the reason I can't create generic array types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java)). The source code can look like this:

```
public static <T> T[][] swap_rows_columns_str_arr(T[][] arr) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[][] new_arr = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(
            arr.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType(),
            arr[0].length, 
            arr.length);
    for (int col = 0; col < arr[0].length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
            new_arr[col][row] = arr[row][col];
        }
    }
    return new_arr;
}
```

This only works for non-primitive types, as primitive types cannot be used in generics. For the primitive types you have to create eight overloads of this method.