# Return type of varargs and generics

Tags: java, arrays, generics, variadic-functions

I was learning Java about how *varargs* works with the generic types. There was this function when I tried to return an array of generic types, which in this case `T` is `String`

```java
static <T> T[] toArr(T... listObj){
    System.out.println("To arr");
    System.out.println(listObj.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(listObj[0].getClass().getName());
    return listObj;
}

static <T> T[] getArr1(T a1, T a2){
    System.out.println("Get arr 1");
    System.out.println(a1.getClass().getName());
    return toArr(a1, a2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] res1 = getArr1("one", "two");
}
```

And the output was this

```
Get arr 1
java.lang.String
To arr
[Ljava.lang.Object;
java.lang.String
//Error: casting from [Ljava.lang.Object to [Ljava.lang.String
```

From my understanding, while 2 `String` objects were passed from `getArr1` to `toArr`, the array storing them were treated as `Object` array, or `T = Object`. When receiving the return from `toArr` (`Object[]`), the failure to convert to `String[]` at `getArr1` throw the exception.

Thing went differently when I explicitly declare the type with method `getArr2`.

```java
static String[] getArr2(String a1, String a2){
    System.out.println("Get arr 2");
    System.out.println(a1.getClass().getName());
    return toArr(a1, a2);
}
```

Which outputs to

```
Get arr 2
java.lang.String
To arr
[Ljava.lang.String;
java.lang.String
```

Went well, no error at all. The *varargs* were treated as `String[]`

May I get some explanation how *varargs* was treated differently given the same input type as above cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, varargs are just syntax sugar for "creating an array of the parameters just before the method is called". That is, a simple varargs method call like this:

```
method("foo", "bar");

// ...

public static void method(String... params) { }
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```
String[] params = new String[] { "foo", "bar" };
method(params);

// ...

public static void method(String[] params) { }
```

Second, [you cannot create arrays of `T`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2927391/5133585) (generic type parameters). `new T[]` is not allowed. This is because `T` does not exist at runtime. The runtime does not know what `T` is. See also: [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

So what happens at the callsite of `toArr`?

```
return toArr(a1, a2);
```

well, `a1` and `a2` are both `T`s here, but we can't do this:

```
T[] params = new T[] { a1, a2 };
return toArr(params);
```

The compiler can only create an `Object[]` here to store the parameters:

```
Object[] params = new Object[] { a1, a2 };
return toArr(params);
```

On the other hand, in `getArr2`, `a1` and `a2` are `String`s, so the compiler knows that it can create a `String[]` to store them.

Comment: So basically in `getArr1` because <all of the passing stuff was done in compile-time> and <generic type was used> --> Compiler has to handle them in some pre-defined rules, in this case `Object[]` is created to pass instead of `T[]` --> In Run-time, `String` is provided but `Object[]` is already embeded in `varargs`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @JohnPham yeah I think you did understand it. The important point is that the type of the array is decided at compile time.

Comment: @JohnPham: " In Run-time, String is provided but Object[] is already embeded in varargs." I am not sure what you mean by this. At runtime, the method has no way of knowing what `T` is. Even if an element of the array is a `String` object, `T` might still be `String`, `Object`, or `Serializable`, etc. And since arrays in Java know their component type at runtime (`Object[]` and `String[]` are different types at runtime), there is no way for the method to create the right runtime type of array. The compiler gives you a warning in the last line of `getArr1()` due to this issue.

Comment: @newacct I think OP is referring to the fact that, even if strings are passed to `getArr1`, the varargs array is still an `Object[]`, because what type of array to create is already decided at compile time. And no, if I remember correctly, there was no warning in the last line of `getArr1` (not in IntelliJ anyway). The warning is in the varargs parameter of `toArr`, saying something about possible pollution.

Comment: @Sweeper: I get a warning in both the last line of `getArr1` and in the parameters of `toArr` (in Oracle JDK 11).